# Android Studio using existing android sdk

Tags: android, android-studio

I already have the latest android sdk with all platforms/sources/etc downloaded.
How can i tell Android Studio to use an existing android sdk without moving it to `android-studio\sdk\`?

Comment: Try it : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16581752/android-studio-change-android-sdk-path

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26562229/how-to-download-android-studio-ide-without-the-sdk/31698468#31698468

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Follow this:

- Open up your project in Android Studio.
- Go to Settings for the Project via F4. Or selecting the Project Root -> Right-Click and then Module Settings.
- You will find **Project Settings** and **Module Settings** under which you have the option of selecting both your JDK and Android SDKs if you want.
- For e.g. under **Platform Settings**, you will find **SDKs** and you can simply tap on the green + sign to add your own path to a locally present SDK.

Hope this helps.

[image]

Answer (score 14):

Go to **Configure** > **Project Defaults** > **Project Structure**. There is a setting: **SDK Location**.

Changing that will make AS use the specified SDK (instead of the one it comes with) for all your projects.

Answer (score 4):

How you do it without having to download another 1GB android sdk:

While installing Android Studio, you have an option to install Custom or Standard.

Choose Custom, and then set the location of your android SDK to where your SDK currently resides.

A red message will appear saying that an existing SDK installation was detected and that only outdated and missing plugins will be installed.

:)

Comment: I'm new with Android studio. I already have installed till SDK 20 I used with Eclipse in my PC . Do I have to download the Studio bundle or only the Android Studio and then choose Custom as you suggested above? I'd like to not have to download twice many Gb of sdk with my 3G connection.

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio

Go to

```
File -> project Structure into Project Structure
Left -> SDK Location
SDK location select Android SDK location (old version use Press +, add another sdk)
```