# How to "download" Android Studio IDE without the SDK?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-2.2-froyo

I already have Android SDK latest edition and Eclipse installed. But I want to try Android Studio as well.

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16582892/android-studio-using-existing-android-sdk) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16581752/android-studio-how-to-change-android-sdk-path) post, but those solutions change the instance of SDK Android Studio (once downloaded and installed) uses. What I want is not to download another SDK when I already have it installed on my machine.

The problem is that the download package given [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html) includes SDK as well.

**So can I download Android Studio IDE without the SDK, and then give the path to the SDK I already have during installation?**

Comment: SDK is just a directory within the Android Studio, why you do not want to download it?

Comment: @Alex I use a slowish internet connection, so it is taking ages to download. Secondly deletion after downloading it would be extra fuss.

Comment: @AlexanderKulyakhtin because the SDK is also used by other applications (e.g. Xamarin) and might already have been installed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well now Google offers a "No Android SDK" version of Android Studio in its [official Download portal](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#downloads):

[image]

Comment: Will it be same like some one downloads the recommended version and then opt out to install the sdk after running setup?

Comment: Not getting this option now.

Answer (score 15):

All the answers suggest to download it with an SDK and then delete it.

You **can** however download the AStudio w/o the SDK from [Android Tools Project Site](http://tools.android.com/download/studio/).

The latest build (2.0 Preview 4) can be downloaded [here](http://tools.android.com/download/studio/canary/latest).

Note: The newest version also requires the SDK to be outside the application folder!

Comment: Hey I checked that but it provides 0.8.14 version while the latest version according to the official download site is v0.8.6. Are you using 0.8.14? If you can tell me there won't be problems with this version, I can download this one.

Comment: @Zarah I'm using 0.8.14 since yesterday and it seems to be working fine. While the whole AStudio is still in beta, the older builds are considered *more stable* than the new builds which are released some-what weekly. It's up to you what you use.

Comment: For anyone coming back to this, [this](https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/download/studio/stable) is where you want to go if you want to download the stable release. Pick your version, and on the next page you'll see what you want.

Answer (score 4):

It is an old question but it might help someone like me who is looking for an answer. This instructions are for windows 64 bit systems.

1. Download zip of Android studio without SDK using links given in other answers (e.g. I downloaded android-studio-ide-141.2112779-windows.zip - version 1.3.0.9)
2. Unzip the archive and run bin/studio64.exe
3. When it asks for the path to install the SDK, browse your existing SDK location instead of the default path given.

If it detects valid installation of SDK, it will display a message that only missing or old component will be downloaded.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can find it here (http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Other) in the "**Other Download Options**" section. There is many different version of Android SDK and Android Studio, including **Android Studio without bundled SDK tools**.

Answer (score 0):

You can download it with SDK, then change it to yours ( [here is explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16582892/android-studio-using-existing-android-sdk) ) and then delete it

Comment: -1 because the OP clearly specified that he does not want to download the SDK again, and that existing answers already explain how to do it by downloading the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download Android Studio as is.
2. Go to it's location and delete the SDK (optional).
3. At your project open "project structure" and set SDK locations to your Eclipse's SDK.

or just copy your Eclispse sdk to android studio SDK.