# How to choose Language Level for new project in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

On this screen:
[image]

How do I know which value to select for Language Level?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which JDK version is required for Android studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17869069/which-jdk-version-is-required-for-android-studio)

Comment: It wasn't apparent from the Google results that that question was about the language level. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: I have edited the other question to make its title clearer

Comment: Well, there's your lesson - at least make the effort to click on those results and skim through them (and incidentally, I've voted approve for your edit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select Level 6 where annotations are introduced and majority of the android projects do follow the same level. Level 7 is introduced recently and isn't that senior to be compatible for all the IDE's (If at all you may want to use it on Eclipse later).