# How do I change Project language level on Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio

I would like to set the Java version I'm using on Android Studio.

How do I set the 'Project language level' like I do on Intellij inside 'Project Structure...' --> 'Project'?

Comment: Check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20270190/how-to-choose-language-level-for-new-project-in-android-studio

Comment: Thanks, saw this question but this is a dialog for a new project and I'm already working on an existing one

Comment: But you must have gone through that and there must be some provision of doing it again for existing one .. In Android studio I am not sure but I in Eclipse I can update things after also ..

Comment: @hagrawal Yes there should be such an option, but there isn't (an intuitive one). Look here (android studio 2.1) http://imgur.com/XY8rupT. In Intellij this is where you set the project language, in Android studio it is empty.

Comment: Thanks @peer. So, what do you do if you want to change the java version?

Comment: @Hadas No idea, sorry... I'm afraid one has to edit the gradle files

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can also edit this inside the Project Structure

[image]

Comment: Not present in Android Studio 3.6 :(

Comment: @AndrewS You can find it now in **Project Structure -> Modules -> Properties**.

Answer (score 15):

Sample build.gradle file which allows me to use lambdas in Android Studio 2.1:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.geniuscreations.successtaskanalyzer"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    jackOptions {
        enabled true
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
}
```

[Java 8 Language Features | Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/preview/j8-jack.html)

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your build.gradle(Module:app):

```
android{
...

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

...
}
```