# Java 8 + Android? Is this possible?

Tags: java, android

Is there any way to compile Android applications with Java 8? And if not, will there ever be a way?

I know the Android libraries and the Java libraries are two seperate things, but what about the syntax? I really like the new use of `->` that they have added and would love to be able to use it.

Comment: There probably will, but as of right now up until Java 7 is supported.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17869069/which-jdk-version-language-level-is-required-for-android-studio

Answer (score 0):

According to official Android documentation JDK6 is supported, so you should use that.

**Source:** https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html