# Android Studio there is nothing to update

Tags: android, android-studio

I am very new to android just started to learn. I have installed android Studio. When I do launch it, it tries to update components, but it fails to update anything. A message does appear saying there is nothing to update and when I click finish, nothing happens.

I have attached a screenshot of error. Please let me know how to solve the problem.
Thanks in advance.

```
There is nothing to install or update.
The following SDK components were not installed: platform-tools, extra-android-m2repository, tools, addon-google_apis-google-21, build-tools-21.1.2, android-21, sys-img-x86-addon-google_apis-google-21, source-21, extra-google-m2repository
```

Comment: Check your proxy setting
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27376465/android-studio-doesnt-start-fails-saying-components-not-installed

Answer (score 3):

This is how i fixed the problem with my installation - 
Go to your C:\Users\"User_NAME"\.AndroidStudio\config\options directory and open 'other.xml'.

then either update value for option USE_PROXY_PAC as true

OR

Set up values for PROXY settings there.

Launch Android Studio after this.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. visited different diffident Stack-overflow questions but nothing helped me. you will have to update these things manually from SDK manager. SDK Manager is by default located at C:\Users[Your-User-Name]\AppData\Local\Android\sdk and AppData folder is by default hidden so you will have to make it visible from Control panel and folder option.

In my case i only *updated SDK components like extra-android-m2repository, tools, addon-google_apis-google-21 and etc, didn't install anything new.*

I think this is the easiest way to get rid of this problem.