# Why Android Studio 1.0.1 on OS X (Yosemite) fails to download SDK components?

Tags: android, macos, android-studio

I've downloaded the newest (1.0.1) AS and have gotten it to install. However, when I go to run it and it wants to download the SDK, it fails with timeouts. I've had similar problems in the past with Eclipse and the Android SDK, which I had to get around by setting 'Force https as http" and the proxy as google.com:80.

I tried going to the network settings under System Preferences and set the http/https proxies to google.com, port 80, but no luck - other than browser problems.

If I try this in an Ubuntu VM on the Mac, I have no problems (other than slow downloads). I'd love to know why OS X has these problems and only with the Android SDK. Can anyone help me get around this problem?

Thanks.

UPDATE:  This is the error message I get after unsuccessfully trying to get the SDK:

```
The following SDK components were not installed: extra-android-m2repository, 
addon google_apis-google-21, extra-intel-hardware_accelerated_execution_manager, 
sys-img-x86-addon-google_apis-google-21, source-21, extra-google-m2repository
```

This is the log:

```
2014-12-19 18:58:12,213 [      0]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - ------------------------------------------------------ IDE STARTED ------------------------------------------------------ 
2014-12-19 18:58:12,256 [     43]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - IDE: Android Studio (build #AI-135.1641136, 11 Dec 2014 00:00) 
2014-12-19 18:58:12,256 [     43]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - OS: Mac OS X (10.10.1, x86_64) 
2014-12-19 18:58:12,256 [     43]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JRE: 1.6.0_65-b14-466.1-11M4716 (Apple Inc.) 
2014-12-19 18:58:12,256 [     43]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM: 20.65-b04-466.1 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM) 
2014-12-19 18:58:12,261 [     48]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM Args: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -ea -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djna.nosys=true -Djna.boot.library.path= -Djna.debug_load=true -Djna.debug_load.jna=true -Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false -XX:+UseCodeCacheFlushing -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50 -Xverify:none -Xbootclasspath/a:../lib/boot.jar -Xms128m -Xmx750m -XX:MaxPermSize=350m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=96m -XX:+UseCompressedOops -Djb.vmOptionsFile=/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/bin/studio.vmoptions -Didea.java.redist=NoJavaDistribution -Didea.home.path=/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents -Didea.executable=studio -Didea.platform.prefix=AndroidStudio -Didea.paths.selector=AndroidStudio 
2014-12-19 18:58:12,329 [    116]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JNA library loaded (64-bit) in 67 ms 
2014-12-19 18:58:12,359 [    146]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - Snappy library loaded (1.0.5) in 30 ms 
2014-12-19 18:58:12,359 [    146]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - 2014-12-19 18:58:09 [Patch] Original patch does not exist: /var/folders/7s/qh28y09s505b49rprr1sqfh80000gn/T/jetbrains.patch.jar.androidstudio

2014-12-19 18:58:12,397 [    184]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - initializing environment 
2014-12-19 18:58:12,398 [    185]   INFO - .intellij.util.EnvironmentUtil - loading shell env: /bin/bash -l -i -c '/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/bin/printenv.py' '/private/var/folders/7s/qh28y09s505b49rprr1sqfh80000gn/T/intellij-shell-env2862248946868187278.tmp' 
2014-12-19 18:58:15,044 [   2831]   INFO - .intellij.util.EnvironmentUtil - shell environment loaded (21 vars) 
2014-12-19 18:58:15,647 [   3434]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Cannot find optional descriptor intellilang-python-support.xml 
2014-12-19 18:58:16,388 [   4175]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - 21 plugins initialized in 1481 ms 
2014-12-19 18:58:16,388 [   4175]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Loaded bundled plugins: Android Support (10.1.0.1), CVS Integration (11), Commander (1.0.0), Copyright (8.1), Git Integration (8.1), GitHub, Google Cloud Tools For Android Studio (0.2.8), Google Login (1.0), Gradle, Groovy (9.0), I18n for Java, IDEA CORE, IntelliLang (8.0), JUnit (1.0), Maven Integration, Properties Support, Subversion Integration (1.1), Task Management (1.0), Terminal (0.1), TestNG-J (8.0), hg4idea (10.0) 
2014-12-19 18:58:17,524 [   5311]   INFO - ellij.util.io.PagedFileStorage - lower=100; upper=200; buffer=10; max=755630080 
2014-12-19 18:58:17,629 [   5416]   INFO - api.vfs.impl.local.FileWatcher - Starting file watcher: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/bin/fsnotifier 
2014-12-19 18:58:17,714 [   5501]   INFO - api.vfs.impl.local.FileWatcher - Native file watcher is operational. 
2014-12-19 18:58:18,087 [   5874]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $APP_CONFIG$/notifications.xml file is null 
2014-12-19 18:58:18,402 [   6189]   INFO - lij.diagnostic.DebugLogManager - Set DEBUG for the following categories: [] 
2014-12-19 18:58:18,690 [   6477]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $APP_CONFIG$/window.manager.xml file is null 
2014-12-19 18:58:20,078 [   7865]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $APP_CONFIG$/macros.xml file is null 
2014-12-19 18:58:20,081 [   7868]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $APP_CONFIG$/quicklists.xml file is null 
2014-12-19 18:58:21,730 [   9517]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $APP_CONFIG$/studio.build.statistics.xml file is null 
2014-12-19 18:58:21,733 [   9520]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $APP_CONFIG$/androidStudioFirstRun.xml file is null 
2014-12-19 18:58:21,734 [   9521]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $APP_CONFIG$/terminal.xml file is null 
2014-12-19 18:58:21,735 [   9522]   INFO - pl.stores.ApplicationStoreImpl - 85 application components initialized in 5332 ms 
2014-12-19 18:58:21,792 [   9579]   INFO - .intellij.idea.IdeaApplication - App initialization took 11268 ms 
2014-12-19 19:09:39,851 [ 687638]   INFO -                  TestNG Runner - Create TestNG Template Configuration 
2014-12-19 19:09:39,854 [ 687641]   INFO -                  TestNG Runner - Create TestNG Template Configuration 
2014-12-19 19:09:39,908 [ 687695]   INFO - ellij.project.impl.ProjectImpl - 21 project components initialized in 253 ms 
2014-12-19 19:09:39,909 [ 687696]   INFO - le.impl.ModuleManagerComponent - 0 module(s) loaded in 0 ms 
2014-12-19 20:41:33,883 [6201670]   INFO - ateSettings.impl.UpdateChecker - [Patch] Download AI-135.1641136-135.1653844-patch-mac.jar to /private/var/folders/7s/qh28y09s505b49rprr1sqfh80000gn/T/AndroidStudio6531468798388232066patch 
2014-12-19 20:41:40,707 [6208494]   INFO - ateSettings.impl.UpdateChecker - [Patch] moved to /private/var/folders/7s/qh28y09s505b49rprr1sqfh80000gn/T/jetbrains.patch.jar.androidstudio 
2014-12-19 20:41:41,098 [6208885]   INFO - dea.ddms.adb.AdbService$Ddmlib - DDMLib terminated 
2014-12-19 20:41:41,101 [6208888]   INFO - il.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl - START INDEX SHUTDOWN 
2014-12-19 20:41:41,112 [6208899]   INFO - il.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl - END INDEX SHUTDOWN 
2014-12-19 20:41:41,112 [6208899]   INFO - stubs.SerializationManagerImpl - START StubSerializationManager SHUTDOWN 
2014-12-19 20:41:41,113 [6208900]   INFO - stubs.SerializationManagerImpl - END StubSerializationManager SHUTDOWN 
2014-12-19 20:41:41,113 [6208900]   INFO - .history.utils.LocalHistoryLog - Purging local history... 
2014-12-19 20:41:41,114 [6208901]   INFO - .history.utils.LocalHistoryLog - Local history storage successfully closed. 
2014-12-19 20:41:41,123 [6208910]   WARN - api.vfs.impl.local.FileWatcher - Watcher terminated with exit code 0 
2014-12-19 20:41:41,123 [6208910]   INFO - newvfs.persistent.PersistentFS - VFS dispose started 
2014-12-19 20:41:41,138 [6208925]   INFO - newvfs.persistent.PersistentFS - VFS dispose completed 
2014-12-19 20:41:41,176 [6208963]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - ------------------------------------------------------ IDE SHUTDOWN ------------------------------------------------------ 
2014-12-19 20:42:12,849 [      0]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - ------------------------------------------------------ IDE STARTED ------------------------------------------------------ 
2014-12-19 20:42:12,870 [     21]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - IDE: Android Studio (build #AI-135.1653844, 18 Dec 2014 00:00) 
2014-12-19 20:42:12,870 [     21]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - OS: Mac OS X (10.10.1, x86_64) 
2014-12-19 20:42:12,870 [     21]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JRE: 1.6.0_65-b14-466.1-11M4716 (Apple Inc.) 
2014-12-19 20:42:12,870 [     21]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM: 20.65-b04-466.1 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM) 
2014-12-19 20:42:12,926 [     77]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM Args: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -ea -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djna.nosys=true -Djna.boot.library.path= -Djna.debug_load=true -Djna.debug_load.jna=true -Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false -XX:+UseCodeCacheFlushing -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50 -Xverify:none -Xbootclasspath/a:../lib/boot.jar -Xms128m -Xmx750m -XX:MaxPermSize=350m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=96m -XX:+UseCompressedOops -Djb.vmOptionsFile=/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/bin/studio.vmoptions -Didea.java.redist=NoJavaDistribution -Didea.home.path=/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents -Didea.executable=studio -Didea.platform.prefix=AndroidStudio -Didea.paths.selector=AndroidStudio 
2014-12-19 20:42:13,031 [    182]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JNA library loaded (64-bit) in 105 ms 
2014-12-19 20:42:13,077 [    228]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - Snappy library loaded (1.0.5) in 46 ms 
2014-12-19 20:42:13,078 [    229]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - 2014-12-19 20:42:09 [Patch] Original patch does not exist: /var/folders/7s/qh28y09s505b49rprr1sqfh80000gn/T/jetbrains.patch.jar.androidstudio

2014-12-19 20:42:13,083 [    234]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - initializing environment 
2014-12-19 20:42:13,108 [    259]   INFO - .intellij.util.EnvironmentUtil - loading shell env: /bin/bash -l -i -c '/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/bin/printenv.py' '/private/var/folders/7s/qh28y09s505b49rprr1sqfh80000gn/T/intellij-shell-env1583537507244796704.tmp' 
2014-12-19 20:42:14,469 [   1620]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Cannot find optional descriptor intellilang-python-support.xml 
2014-12-19 20:42:14,496 [   1647]   INFO - .intellij.util.EnvironmentUtil - shell environment loaded (21 vars) 
2014-12-19 20:42:15,068 [   2219]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - 21 plugins initialized in 1034 ms 
2014-12-19 20:42:15,068 [   2219]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Loaded bundled plugins: Android Support (10.1.0.2), CVS Integration (11), Commander (1.0.0), Copyright (8.1), Git Integration (8.1), GitHub, Google Cloud Tools For Android Studio (0.2.8), Google Login (1.0), Gradle, Groovy (9.0), I18n for Java, IDEA CORE, IntelliLang (8.0), JUnit (1.0), Maven Integration, Properties Support, Subversion Integration (1.1), Task Management (1.0), Terminal (0.1), TestNG-J (8.0), hg4idea (10.0) 
2014-12-19 20:42:15,477 [   2628]   INFO - ellij.util.io.PagedFileStorage - lower=100; upper=200; buffer=10; max=755630080 
2014-12-19 20:42:15,540 [   2691]   INFO - api.vfs.impl.local.FileWatcher - Starting file watcher: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/bin/fsnotifier 
2014-12-19 20:42:15,559 [   2710]   INFO - api.vfs.impl.local.FileWatcher - Native file watcher is operational. 
2014-12-19 20:42:15,951 [   3102]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $APP_CONFIG$/notifications.xml file is null 
2014-12-19 20:42:16,286 [   3437]   INFO - lij.diagnostic.DebugLogManager - Set DEBUG for the following categories: [] 
2014-12-19 20:42:16,456 [   3607]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $APP_CONFIG$/window.manager.xml file is null 
2014-12-19 20:42:17,046 [   4197]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $APP_CONFIG$/macros.xml file is null 
2014-12-19 20:42:17,057 [   4208]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $APP_CONFIG$/quicklists.xml file is null 
2014-12-19 20:42:18,845 [   5996]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $APP_CONFIG$/studio.build.statistics.xml file is null 
2014-12-19 20:42:18,849 [   6000]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $APP_CONFIG$/androidStudioFirstRun.xml file is null 
2014-12-19 20:42:18,850 [   6001]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $APP_CONFIG$/terminal.xml file is null 
2014-12-19 20:42:18,852 [   6003]   INFO - pl.stores.ApplicationStoreImpl - 85 application components initialized in 3773 ms 
2014-12-19 20:42:18,862 [   6013]   INFO - .intellij.idea.IdeaApplication - App initialization took 9494 ms 
2014-12-19 20:53:51,153 [ 698304]   INFO -                  TestNG Runner - Create TestNG Template Configuration 
2014-12-19 20:53:51,155 [ 698306]   INFO -                  TestNG Runner - Create TestNG Template Configuration 
2014-12-19 20:53:51,180 [ 698331]   INFO - ellij.project.impl.ProjectImpl - 21 project components initialized in 150 ms 
2014-12-19 20:53:51,181 [ 698332]   INFO - le.impl.ModuleManagerComponent - 0 module(s) loaded in 0 ms 
2014-12-19 20:53:53,537 [ 700688]   INFO - ntellij.util.proxy.CommonProxy - You have JVM property "https.proxyHost" set to "www.google.com".
This may lead to incorrect behaviour. Proxy should be set in Settings | HTTP Proxy
This JVM property is old and its usage is not recommended by Oracle.

(Note: It could have been assigned by some code dynamically.) 
2014-12-19 20:53:53,538 [ 700689]   INFO - ntellij.util.proxy.CommonProxy - You have JVM property "https.proxyHost" set to "www.google.com".
This may lead to incorrect behaviour. Proxy should be set in Settings | HTTP Proxy
This JVM property is old and its usage is not recommended by Oracle.

(Note: It could have been assigned by some code dynamically.) 
2014-12-19 20:57:38,996 [ 926147]   INFO - ntellij.util.proxy.CommonProxy - You have JVM property "https.proxyHost" set to "www.google.com".
This may lead to incorrect behaviour. Proxy should be set in Settings | HTTP Proxy
This JVM property is old and its usage is not recommended by Oracle.
```

The JDK is 1.6.0_65 - the Apple one. According to the instructions, the IDE should be run with JRE 6 for better font rendering.

I don't know where the proxyHost is coming from unless it is using the androidtool.cfg file in the .android directory from installing the Eclipse version. I may try renaming the .android directory to remove that as a possible issue.

BTW, I've upgraded from 1.0.1 to 1.0.2. Same deal.

UPDATE 2: I removed all AndroidStudio directories and did a complete re-install. Here is the new log (this one has a stacktrace):

```
2014-12-20 13:48:15,987 [      0]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - ------------------------------------------------------ IDE STARTED ------------------------------------------------------ 
2014-12-20 13:48:16,011 [     24]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - IDE: Android Studio (build #AI-135.1641136, 11 Dec 2014 00:00) 
2014-12-20 13:48:16,011 [     24]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - OS: Mac OS X (10.10.1, x86_64) 
2014-12-20 13:48:16,011 [     24]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JRE: 1.6.0_65-b14-466.1-11M4716 (Apple Inc.) 
2014-12-20 13:48:16,011 [     24]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM: 20.65-b04-466.1 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM) 
2014-12-20 13:48:16,016 [     29]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM Args: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -ea -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djna.nosys=true -Djna.boot.library.path= -Djna.debug_load=true -Djna.debug_load.jna=true -Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false -XX:+UseCodeCacheFlushing -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50 -Xverify:none -Xbootclasspath/a:../lib/boot.jar -Xms128m -Xmx750m -XX:MaxPermSize=350m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=96m -XX:+UseCompressedOops -Djb.vmOptionsFile=/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/bin/studio.vmoptions -Didea.java.redist=NoJavaDistribution -Didea.home.path=/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents -Didea.executable=studio -Didea.platform.prefix=AndroidStudio -Didea.paths.selector=AndroidStudio 
2014-12-20 13:48:16,066 [     79]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JNA library loaded (64-bit) in 49 ms 
2014-12-20 13:48:16,081 [     94]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - Snappy library loaded (1.0.5) in 15 ms 
2014-12-20 13:48:16,081 [     94]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main -     2014-12-20 13:48:14 [Patch] Original patch does not exist: /var/folders/7s/qh28y09s505b49rprr1sqfh80000gn/T/jetbrains.patch.jar.androidstudio

2014-12-20 13:48:16,086 [     99]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - initializing environment 
2014-12-20 13:48:16,087 [    100]   INFO - .intellij.util.EnvironmentUtil - loading shell env: /bin/bash -l -i -c '/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/bin/printenv.py' '/private/var/folders/7s/qh28y09s505b49rprr1sqfh80000gn/T/intellij-shell-env720346877295611740.tmp' 
2014-12-20 13:48:17,135 [   1148]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Cannot find optional descriptor intellilang-python-support.xml 
2014-12-20 13:48:17,564 [   1577]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - 21 plugins initialized in 780 ms 
2014-12-20 13:48:17,564 [   1577]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Loaded bundled plugins: Android Support (10.1.0.1), CVS Integration (11), Commander (1.0.0), Copyright (8.1), Git Integration (8.1), GitHub, Google Cloud Tools For Android Studio (0.2.8), Google Login (1.0), Gradle, Groovy (9.0), I18n for Java, IDEA CORE, IntelliLang (8.0), JUnit (1.0), Maven Integration, Properties Support, Subversion Integration (1.1), Task Management (1.0), Terminal (0.1), TestNG-J (8.0), hg4idea (10.0) 
2014-12-20 13:48:17,652 [   1665]   INFO - .intellij.util.EnvironmentUtil - shell environment loaded (22 vars) 
2014-12-20 13:48:17,969 [   1982]   INFO - ellij.vfs.persistent.FSRecords - Marking VFS as corrupted 
2014-12-20 13:48:17,970 [   1983]   INFO - ellij.util.io.PagedFileStorage - lower=100; upper=200; buffer=10; max=755630080 
2014-12-20 13:48:18,182 [   2195]   INFO - api.vfs.impl.local.FileWatcher - Starting file watcher: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/bin/fsnotifier 
2014-12-20 13:48:18,196 [   2209]   INFO - api.vfs.impl.local.FileWatcher - Native file watcher is operational. 
2014-12-20 13:48:18,356 [   2369]   INFO - .history.utils.LocalHistoryLog - local history version mismatch (was: 0, expected: 5), rebuilding... 
2014-12-20 13:48:18,356 [   2369]   INFO - .history.utils.LocalHistoryLog - FS has been rebuild, rebuilding local history... 
2014-12-20 13:48:18,413 [   2426]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $APP_CONFIG$/notifications.xml file is null 
2014-12-20 13:48:18,594 [   2607]   INFO - lij.diagnostic.DebugLogManager - Set DEBUG for the following categories: [] 
2014-12-20 13:48:18,748 [   2761]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $APP_CONFIG$/window.manager.xml file is null 
2014-12-20 13:48:23,189 [   7202]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $APP_CONFIG$/macros.xml file is null 
2014-12-20 13:48:23,190 [   7203]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $APP_CONFIG$/quicklists.xml file is null 
2014-12-20 13:48:24,180 [   8193]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $APP_CONFIG$/studio.build.statistics.xml file is null 
2014-12-20 13:48:24,184 [   8197]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $APP_CONFIG$/androidStudioFirstRun.xml file is null 
2014-12-20 13:48:24,185 [   8198]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $APP_CONFIG$/terminal.xml file is null 
2014-12-20 13:48:24,186 [   8199]   INFO - pl.stores.ApplicationStoreImpl - 85 application components initialized in 6611 ms 
2014-12-20 13:48:24,195 [   8208]   INFO - .intellij.idea.IdeaApplication - App initialization took 9195 ms 
2014-12-20 14:25:25,839 [2229852]   INFO -                  TestNG Runner - Create TestNG Template Configuration 
2014-12-20 14:25:25,848 [2229861]   INFO -                  TestNG Runner - Create TestNG Template Configuration 
2014-12-20 14:25:25,873 [2229886]   INFO - ellij.project.impl.ProjectImpl - 21 project components initialized in 171 ms 
2014-12-20 14:25:25,873 [2229886]   INFO - le.impl.ModuleManagerComponent - 0 module(s) loaded in 0 ms 
2014-12-20 14:49:41,337 [3685350]  ERROR - tRunWizard$SetupProgressStep$1 - The following SDK components were not installed: extra-android-m2repository, addon-google_apis-google-21, extra-intel-hardware_accelerated_execution_manager, sys-img-x86-addon-google_apis-google-21, source-21, extra-google-m2repository 
com.android.tools.idea.welcome.WizardException: The following SDK components were not installed: extra-android-m2repository, addon-google_apis-google-21, extra-intel-hardware_accelerated_execution_manager, sys-img-x86-addon-google_apis-google-21, source-21, extra-google-m2repository
        at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.InstallOperation.promptToRetry(InstallOperation.java:109)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.InstallComponentsOperation.perform(InstallComponentsOperation.java:80)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.InstallComponentsOperation.perform(InstallComponentsOperation.java:39)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.InstallOperation$1.compute(InstallOperation.java:80)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.InstallContext$Wrapper.run(InstallContext.java:127)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.ProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManager.java:209)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:212)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.ProgressStep.run(ProgressStep.java:167)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.InstallContext.run(InstallContext.java:77)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.InstallOperation.execute(InstallOperation.java:72)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.InstallOperation$OperationChain.perform(InstallOperation.java:148)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.InstallOperation.execute(InstallOperation.java:68)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.InstallOperation$OperationChain.perform(InstallOperation.java:146)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.InstallOperation.execute(InstallOperation.java:68)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.InstallOperation$OperationChain.perform(InstallOperation.java:146)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.InstallOperation.execute(InstallOperation.java:68)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.InstallComponentsPath.runLongOperation(InstallComponentsPath.java:299)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.FirstRunWizard.doLongRunningOperation(FirstRunWizard.java:125)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.FirstRunWizard.access$000(FirstRunWizard.java:40)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.FirstRunWizard$SetupProgressStep$1.run(FirstRunWizard.java:151)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.FirstRunWizardHost$LongRunningOperationWrapper.run(FirstRunWizardHost.java:432)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$TaskRunnable.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:471)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$2.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:178)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.ProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManager.java:209)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:212)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.runProcess(ProgressManagerImpl.java:171)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$8.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:380)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:419)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:149)
2014-12-20 14:49:41,341 [3685354]  ERROR - tRunWizard$SetupProgressStep$1 - Android Studio 1.0.1  Build #AI-135.1641136 
2014-12-20 14:49:41,342 [3685355]  ERROR - tRunWizard$SetupProgressStep$1 - JDK: 1.6.0_65 
2014-12-20 14:49:41,342 [3685355]  ERROR - tRunWizard$SetupProgressStep$1 - VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 
2014-12-20 14:49:41,342 [3685355]  ERROR - tRunWizard$SetupProgressStep$1 - Vendor: Apple Inc. 
2014-12-20 14:49:41,342 [3685355]  ERROR - tRunWizard$SetupProgressStep$1 - OS: Mac OS X 
2014-12-20 14:49:41,342 [3685355]  ERROR - tRunWizard$SetupProgressStep$1 - Last Action:  
2014-12-20 14:49:45,160 [3689173]   INFO - dea.ddms.adb.AdbService$Ddmlib - DDMLib terminated 
2014-12-20 14:49:45,164 [3689177]   INFO - il.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl - START INDEX SHUTDOWN 
2014-12-20 14:49:45,172 [3689185]   INFO - il.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl - END INDEX SHUTDOWN 
2014-12-20 14:49:45,172 [3689185]   INFO - stubs.SerializationManagerImpl - START StubSerializationManager SHUTDOWN 
2014-12-20 14:49:45,173 [3689186]   INFO - stubs.SerializationManagerImpl - END StubSerializationManager SHUTDOWN 
2014-12-20 14:49:45,173 [3689186]   INFO - .history.utils.LocalHistoryLog - Purging local history... 
2014-12-20 14:49:45,173 [3689186]   INFO - .history.utils.LocalHistoryLog - Local history storage successfully closed. 
2014-12-20 14:49:45,196 [3689209]   WARN - api.vfs.impl.local.FileWatcher - Watcher terminated with exit code 0 
2014-12-20 14:49:45,196 [3689209]   INFO - newvfs.persistent.PersistentFS - VFS dispose started 
2014-12-20 14:49:45,197 [3689210]   INFO - newvfs.persistent.PersistentFS - VFS dispose completed 
2014-12-20 14:49:45,200 [3689213]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - ------------------------------------------------------ IDE SHUTDOWN ------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: take a look at the log file of AndroidStudio (maybe post it here)

Comment: where do I find the log file?

Comment: usually here : ~/Library/Logs/AndroidStudio/idea.log

Comment: @ben75 thanks. i'll look for it and post it.

Comment: Can you try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/27518631/1180117

Comment: @Kiran You did it! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For me, this issue was proxy related. In Mac osx, *even while above error is displayed, there is menu bar for Android Studio at top*. Select preferences `Android Studio -> Preferences` and change proxy as below and issue was resolved. There could be similar options in Windows/Linux to access preferences page while error is being displayed.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I got following error on mac

"The following SDK components were not installed: tools, extra-android-m2repository, build-tools-21.1.2, sys-img-x86-addon-google_apis-google-21"

It occurs because of absence of some tools.

Download https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/build-tools_r21.1.2-macosx.zip and unzip it

Check [this](http://blog.csdn.net/gyming/article/details/8168166) to find other missed android tools

Enjoy coding..:)