# Android SDK component was not installed on mac os 10.10.1

Tags: android, macos

I downloaded the latest version of Android Studio and installed.When the program setup, this message always show up.I cannot figure it out why.And I have done some research such as the OS version problem and.......after that i click the button "retry" for many times but still don't work.thank you in advance.My english is poor,sorry.

> The following SDK component was not installed: sys-img-x86-addon-google_apis-google-21

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27376465/android-studio-doesnt-start-fails-saying-components-not-installed

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by running the wizard again, this time choosing the Custom installation and checking the Lollypop SDK for download and install.