# Error when run Android studio IDE

Tags: android, android-studio, ide

When I launch Android studio I encounter this Error:

[image]

```
    The following SDK components were not installed: build-tools-21.1.1, source-21, sys-img-x86-addon-google_apis-google-21, 
    extra-android-m2repository, android-21, extra-google-m2repository, addon-google_apis-google-21, tools, platform-tools
```

And when I click retry, it gives me the same error:

[image]

Comment: Execute your `AndroidStudio.exe` as `Run as Admin`

Comment: Gives again same error

Comment: Have you downloaded a full SDK?

Comment: Yes, I had download android studio with SDK!

Comment: I download full sdk pack from this site and again download android studio without sdk and when install this version of android studio I set sdk path it and run it but when run emulator is very slow and I can't install api24 when I want install it occur error! I download sdk package from http://goo.gl/HpHozj . You can view details in image in that page.

Comment: Hi @Farshid, Did you find a solution for this problem finally?

Comment: The team working on Android Studio are busy enjoying Free Snacks.

Comment: Its worked for me as M D said, run as admin.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Studio doesn't start, fails saying components not installed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27376465/android-studio-doesnt-start-fails-saying-components-not-installed)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Configure a proxy for Android studio by modifying *other.xml* file at:

> C:\Users\"Your account"\.AndroidStudio\config\options\other.xml

Then change the proxy configurations as follows:

```
<option name="USE_HTTP_PROXY" value="true" />
<option name="USE_PROXY_PAC" value="false" />
<option name="PROXY_HOST" value="your_proxy_server" />
<option name="PROXY_PORT" value="your_proxy_port" />
```

Comment: This solved the first part of my problem which was that it couldn't install `tools and extra-android m2repository`, then after that I had the same error but for `build-tools-21.1.1` which I solved using Alexander Prokofyev's solution.

Comment: it worked for me. Thanks :) I think android studio should ask for proxy settings at start if it is unable to connect to internet

Answer (score 12):

code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=82789

1. download build-tools21.1.1 [google link](http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/build-tools_r21.1.1-windows.zip) or [dehkadeco.ir](http://dehkadeco.ir/%D9%85%D9%82%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%AA-%D8%A2%D9%85%D9%88%D8%B2%D8%B4%DB%8C/android-programming-tutorials/73-was-not-installed-build-tools-21-1-1.html) link
2. sdk will be located under C:\Users\<>\AppData\Local\Android\sdk.
3. You may find that 21.1.2 is already in place 
   C:\Users\<>\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools
   Create a folder with name "21.1.1" under this.
4. Copy all the files from the downloaded build-tools:21.1.1 under android-5.0 to  C:\Users\<>\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\21.1.1
5. Start the Android studio now.

Comment: I had this problem too and solved it this way, but I had to use Erfan Jazeb Nikoo's method first for the first set of problems. Then I got different errors and solved it this way.

Comment: This worked for me. But then Google, shouldn't it just work? Even in offline mode...

Answer (score 3):

Try to rename folder `21.1.2` inside Android SDK `build-tools` folder (in my case it was `c:\Users\prokofyev\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\21.1.2`) to `android-5.0`  (in my case it became `c:\Users\prokofyev\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\android-5.0`). This way I fixed similar error on new Android Studio installation.

Comment: First I had to do what Erfan Jazeb Nikboo suggested, then I think I had the same problem as you. In the application I was told that it couldn't download build-tools 21.1.1, but inside build-tools I had folder 21.1.2. I downloaded 21.1.1 from here: http://downloads.puresoftware.org/files/android/build-tools/ and put it in build-tools with and named the folder 21.1.1 and that solved my problems.

Comment: To clarify, when you download the build-tools-21.1.1.zip file, it actually contains a folder named "android-5.0", rather than "21.1.1" as you might expect.  I downloaded that, extracted it to the build-tools directory (so now I had both a "21.1.2" and a "android-5.0" directory, I hit "retry" on the error message and it succeeded.  Although it finished with a new error "Unable to create a virtual device: Unable to create Android virtual device".

Answer (score 2):

Android Studio was not able to connect to internet in my work PC due to Intranet Proxy/Firewall settings, changing the proxy settings didnt help me either.

Android studio was failing to run as it requires to install the above mentioned packages. As a work around I installed the packages from **Android SDK Manager** and it solved it.

You can find the SDK Manager under **C:\Users\< UserName> \AppData\Local\Android\sdk\SDK Manager.exe**
In the GUI choose the following options whichever is relavant.

- Tools->All Android SDK Build-tools and SDK Platform-tools under version 21.*
- Everything under Android 5.0.1(API 21)
- Everything under Extras

After installation is complete try launching the Android Studio

Answer (score 1):

Some tools are missing.

Download [build-tools_r21.1.1-windows.zip](http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/build-tools_r21.1.1-windows.zip) and unzip it. Run Android Studio again.

If you get similar error again Check [this](http://blog.csdn.net/gyming/article/details/8168166) for missing android tools.

Enjoy coding..:)

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens when you can not download sdk from google, try to download it manually.

You can get the build you mentioned at google or bellow link:

[this link](http://dehkadeco.ir/downloads/category/2-uncat.html?download=4:%D8%AF%D8%A7%D9%86%D9%84%D9%88%D8%AF-build-tools21)

Unzip it in **\sdk\build-tools**

Answer (score 1):

Adding to answer by @Erfan , If you are using **automatic configuration script** instead of a proxy server , Change the settings as below :

> C:\Users\"Your account".AndroidStudio\config\options\other.xml

Then change the line about proxy configurations like this:

```
<component name="HttpConfigurable">
        <option name="PROXY_TYPE_IS_SOCKS" value="false" />
        <option name="USE_HTTP_PROXY" value="false" />
        <option name="USE_PROXY_PAC" value="true" />
        <option name="PROXY_HOST" value="" />
        <option name="PROXY_PORT" value="80" />
        <option name="PROXY_AUTHENTICATION" value="true" />
        <option name="PROXY_LOGIN" value=" your User Name" />
        <option name="PROXY_PASSWORD_CRYPT" value=" Your Domain Password " />
        <option name="KEEP_PROXY_PASSWORD" value="false" />
        <option name="myGenericPasswords">
          <map />
        </option>
        <option name="myGenericCancelled">
          <set />
        </option>
        <option name="PROXY_EXCEPTIONS" value="" />
        <option name="USE_PAC_URL" value="true" />
        <option name="PAC_URL" value=" Put Pac Url Here mentioned in Auto Config Script " />
      </component>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, But when I opened the studio **"as administrator"** error has gone!!! And my problem solved!!!! In my case I have installed the sdk in different location since I don't want install anything on my user folder.

[image]

There is one more thing I have done that is I made the folder as writable from read access. (But I don't think this step is necessary)

Answer (score 0):

download build-tools:21.1.1 from [build-tools_r21.1.1-windows.zip](http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/build-tools_r21.1.1-windows.zip)

and unzip, it will extract the entire folder to copy or move your sdk /build-tools folder.
name folder must be build-tools_21.1.1

Comment: I can't understand your answer

Comment: The following SDK components were not installed: build-tools-21.1.1.this error means you don't download sdk commponents. So at the first you must download build-tools:21.1.1 package from http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/build-tools_r21.1.1-windows.zip. and goto sdk path and goto build-tools folder and unzip your package into build-tools-21.1.1 folder.

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu users, check that the folder where the SDK will be installed has permissions.

Answer (score 0):

**I also had the same problem. See the picture below:**

[image]

**Solution: Run it as an administrator.**

[image]

Comment: If you look at to comments under question, I tested this way before but not worked!

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry if I didn't read it. It might help those who are having the same error though. Anyway, it's been two weeks and you haven't solved it yet? Have you tried a clean installation?

Comment: I download sdk package from this site(ehsanavr.com) and I download a android studio without sdk and then I installed and now that's work but that's speed is slow!

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting UnknownHostException the the problem lies in the proxy - click the close icon (the X in the upper right corner) and agree to start setup next time again. Then in the Studio itself go to Configure -> Settings -> search for proxy and set up your proxy (auto-detect or manual).

Running as administrator might help as well