# Run Android Studio error- downloading components

Tags: android, android-studio

I Want run Android Studio as administrator, but i saw an error in downloading components:

The following SDK components were not installed: extra-android-m2repository, sys-img-x86-addon-google_apis-google-21, extra-google-m2repository

Comment: Open the SDK Manager and install these: extra-android-m2repository, sys-img-x86-addon-google_apis-google-21, extra-google-m2repository.

Comment: in SDk Manager also it can not install.I think the problem is from proxy but i do not know how to solve IT

Comment: Have you ever tried to allow `SDK Manager.exe` in Firewall (i.e. Windows Firewall). Go to Control Panel > System And Security > Allow a program through Windows Firewall > Allow another program > find `SDK Manager.exe` > OK.

Answer (score 1):

How did you install Android Studio?
It is better to install using exe file at http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Comment: I have downloaded Android studio. After running it, set up wizard start and it tries to download some packages. After a while it shows the above error

Comment: You try to install Android Studio using administrator. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27376465/android-studio-doesnt-start-fails-saying-components-not-installed If still not working, try to rename the folder which is located inside build-tools http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27602279/error-when-run-android-studio-ide