# Android Studio installation for windows fails

Tags: java, android, android-studio, installation, android-sdk-tools

I am trying to install Android Studio behind a proxy.

I have entered proper proxy settings but getting the following error :

> `sys-img-x86-addon-google_apis-google-extra-android-m2repository` and
>   more sdk components were not installed

Trying to download it from SDK Manager, it throws:

> Download interrupted: Unexpected `HTTP Status 403` android studio

Any clue on how can this be solved?

Comment: Take a look to  [Error when run Android studio IDE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27602279/error-when-run-android-studio-ide)

Comment: @JordiCastilla I have already looked and tried and it didnt work as mentioned in my post above. Could you suggest something more to help out with this?

Comment: download last (or desired) [SDK](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html), and retry AS installation manually indicating placement of the SDK....

Answer (score 1):

Try to put your proxy server and port under tools -> options -> proxy settings