# Unable to install AndroidStudio

Tags: android, sdk, android-studio, installation

I have a little problem to start Android Studio. I have this error

> "The following SDK components were not installed:
>   extra-android-m2repository, tools".

I tried to start as Administrator, but it doesn't work. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27376465/android-studio-doesnt-start-fails-saying-components-not-installed? Are you behind a Proxy?

Comment: I tried these two methods. I am on an idea, I will update my post if it works.

Comment: I change the SDK files in C:\Users\[Username]\AppData\Local\Android\sdk and i put a recent one, then i restart the app with the admin rights. Thx for your help :D. 

PS: Should I delete this post ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change the SDK files in

```
C:\Users\[Username]\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
```

and i put a recent one, then i restart the app with the admin rights.