# Could not run Android Studio on my Mac OS Yosemite. Error: The following SDK component was not installed: sys-img-x86-addon-google_apis-google-21

Tags: android, macos

I could not run Android Studio on my Mac OS Yosemite. The installation wizard pops up and finishes the setup with the screen saying **error :**

```
Error: The following SDK component was not installed: 
sys-img-x86-addon-google_apis-google-21.
```

I checked the following question, [Android Studio doesn't start, fails saying components not installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27376465/android-studio-doesnt-start-fails-saying-components-not-installed). Don't know how to get that to Mac

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Try this that is suggested in the link you mention:

Open the terminal and execute these 2 commands:

```
cd /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/
sudo ./studio
```

It seems that you need to run it as administrator the first time you launch it. I haven't tried that but looks promising.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I tried your suggestion and it works.

Answer (score 5):

Run `sudo /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/studio`

Answer (score 0):

When you get the error that the download failed, if you click "Cancel" instead of "Finish", Android Studio should still open. It did for me. Then you can go into the SDK Manager and install the needed components.

But if you still cannot get into Android Studio, you can still access the SDK Manager GUI by going into the directory where the sdk is (the name of the directory will be something like adt-bund-mac-x86 or android-sdk-macosx), in the tools folder, run the android executable. The mac OS doesn't want to run it automatically because it's not signed as being from a reputable developer, but you can run it by right clicking and selecting Open. This runs the SDK Manager and you should be able to install everything you need from there.

Answer (score 0):

Open your terminal and paste below command

```
cd /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/
sudo ./studio
```