# Android Studio didn't start. Shows issue like "tools, extra-android-m2repository and 6 more SDK components were not installed"

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I tried to start Android Studio from cmd line, but show issue like "tools, extra-android-m2repository and 6 more SDK components were not installed". I think there is some problem with the jdk. I even tried to change proxy settings in other.xml, but it opened the Android Studio window , but I cannot able to create or import any new projects. People guide me.

Comment: Check this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27376465/android-studio-doesnt-start-fails-saying-components-not-installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Help and Check for update it will automatically update the required packages and your problem will be solved.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Android SDK-folder and open SDK Manager.exe, from there you can install all the needed packages (Mostly they are already selected).