# "The following SDK components were not installed: sys-img-x86-addon-google_apis-google-22 and addon-google_apis-google-22"

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, windows-7-x64

I'm Windows 7 64-bit user and I got `Android Studio` problem after I update the latest version of `Android Studio` and `SDK` components..

```
The following SDK components were not installed: sys-img-x86-addon-google_apis-google-22 and addon-google_apis-google-22
```

Please help me to resolve this problem. Thank you.

Comment: I am facing the same problem on linux mint, during installation of sdk

Comment: am facing the same problem on windows 8.1 after i update, i think i am going to unistall

Comment: accept which one answer helped you..

Comment: In my case (Windows 10 PC) running Android Studio as **administrator** solved the issue.

Answer (score 43):

I had the same issue when trying to upgrade Android Studio from 1.1 to 1.2 on Mac OS 10.10.

I solved the problem by selecting custom installation instead of standard. Also we need to select the Android SDK Platform (Lollipop 5.1).

Answer (score 12):

[image]

- Choose the new UI Design >> next
- Just try to cancel the "Downloading Components" from upper right
  corner 'X' button.
- A dialog box will appear then click OK (wait a bit for first time
  launch)

Answer (score 6):

I uninstall Only Android studio (keep the SDK and Emulator) and then reinstall it just android studio. took me 2 minutes and my android studio work again.

Answer (score 6):

I had this same problem, but I'm a Linux user.

I resolved the problem by reattempting the installation with adminstrator privileges. [For those Linux users reading this, I ran `studio.sh` with `sudo`.]

Answer (score 6):

I just click 'Retry' and it's ok! Also run on Win7 64-bit.

Answer (score 4):

TRY BELOW SOLUTIONS.

SOLUTION 1:

-> Run Android Studio as Administrator (this is only required for first run or when any issues arise due to automatic updates on any run in future).

Though it shows API 23 is or any other updates are not installed (and wouldn't show any 'Retry' button), BUT still the download and installation of rest of the updates would proceed (you can see the download progress incrementing even after seeing the above errors). So, DO NOT ABORT the operation.

-> At the end of installation (after rest of successful updates are installed) it would this time display the "Retry" button to retry installation for API 23 or any other versions which had failed earlier. Then click the "Retry" button, it would work this time.

This would resolve your issue with successful installation.

-> Next time onward no need to run Android studio as Administrator, unless it does any automatic updates and shows similar issues.

SOLUTION 2:

-> Alternative approach is to install any updates (which ever failed in earlier attempt) from Android SDK Manager first and then later launch Android Studio (which would not need any check for updates and any additional installations).

To install any features or updates, run Android SDK manager as administrator (run as administrator is not mandatory for this but preferred to avoid any permissions related issues) and check the required options and proceed with the installation without any issues.

SOLUTION 3:

-> If still your issue is not resolved, then try the proxy solution as suggested by others or check your internet connectivity if it's working properly or not.

*Any of the above solutions should resolve your issues.

Answer (score 3):

go to c->users->[Your user account]-> remove android 1.2 and restart the android studio
when it ask to import select first radio button which is import setting from previous config

there you go fixed

Answer (score 2):

I am using Windows 7 Professional and I was having same problem @Bayu Mohammad Lufty not worked for me.

I simply delete .AndroidStudio1.2 from my C:\Users\UserName\ and restart my Android studio again.
It open Android Studio perfectly!
It configured everything again in next start :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm a MacOS user.

I solved it by uninstalling Android Studio and reinstalling it again.

If you want to try this link helped me a lot.

[Uninstall Android Studio MacOS (terminal)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18458893)

Answer (score 2):

When you are installing Android Studio, under Install type do not use standard setting, use custom setting instead, and check all the option boxes in the next step.

Answer (score 1):

i have solve my same problem

i update my android studio, and i choose not to import my setting from my previous version than that problem appear.

than i realize that i have 2 AndroidStudio folder on my windows account (.AndroidStudio and .AndroidStudio1.2) and on my new .AndroidStudio1.2 folder there are no other.xml file.

than i copy other.xml file from C:\Users\my windows account name.AndroidStudio\config\options to C:\Users\my windows account name.AndroidStudio1.2\config\options

and that how i solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using UBUNTU and I got this same error. I restarted the set up using sudo and did a custom install. This solved my problem!

--More Specific--

re-installed using # sudo ./studio.sh

then I made sure to click "Custom Install"

then I made sure all packages were selected.

And I got this message Android virtual device Nexus_5_API_22_x86 was successfully created

Answer (score 0):

I just run:
C:\Users[Username]\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\SDK Manager.exe

Install **SDK Platform Android M Preview**

[image]

And run Android Studio again.

It's working for me :D

Answer (score 0):

When this error occured I first clicked retry for few times and waited for 2 minutes and clicked 'retry' then it installed without any error.(for 2 minutes I was searching to solve this problem online).

Answer (score 0):

I was getting an "out of space" error, which left me scratching my head as I had plenty of disk space, until I realized that it ran out of space on `/tmp`, which on Arch Linux is mounted on a `tmpfs` with a size limit.