# Android studio set up

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-studio

I'm trying to install android-studio on my Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit. However my installation stops at a certain point saying

---

> build-tools-19.1.0,sys-img-x86-addon-google_apis-google-19 and 3 more
>   SDK components were not installed

---

do you have any solution?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30004209/the-following-sdk-components-were-not-installed-sys-img-x86-addon-google-apis suggests for a similar error that uninstalling / reinstalling might work?