# Downloading Android Studio

Tags: java

I am trying to install Android Studio on my mac, so I made it to the downloading components part of the downloading process.
I keep on getting this error:

> The following SDK component was not installed:
>   sys-img-x86-addon-google_apis-google-23

I don't know what that means, could anyone help me download this to my computer?
Also, in the step right before it (the SDK Components Setup), I get an message saying

> An existing Android SDK was detected. The setup wizard will only
>   download missing or outdated SDK components

I don't know if this has anything to do with it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["The following SDK components were not installed: sys-img-x86-addon-google\_apis-google-22 and addon-google\_apis-google-22"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30004209/the-following-sdk-components-were-not-installed-sys-img-x86-addon-google-apis)

Comment: Have you tried this link ?
If you haven't please do : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27376465/android-studio-doesnt-start-fails-saying-components-not-installed

Answer (score 0):

Can you open Android Studio and the SDK Manager?
Normally the SDK is under /Users/$USER/Library/Android/ do you have something there?