# The following SDK component was not installed: source-25

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

I am getting this error while installing Android Studio on my  system with Ubuntu version 14.04.

This error occurs at the time when I start my Android studio first time and it starts downloading sdk and all necessary packages required for developing an Android Application and then I get this

***The following SDK component was not installed: source-25.  Ignoring unknown package filter 'source-25'Warning: The package filter removed all packages. There is nothing to install.
         Please consider trying to update again without a package filter.***

Here is the screen shot of the same

[image]

I followed this link ["The following SDK components were not installed: sys-img-x86-addon-google_apis-google-22 and addon-google_apis-google-22"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30004209/the-following-sdk-components-were-not-installed-sys-img-x86-addon-google-apis)
for resolving my issue but that didn't help me.

Comment: Finally I have resolved my issue somehow it was due to installing an earlier version of Android Studio with jdk 1.8. I have downloaded latest version of Android studio and installed the same that resolved the problem **_The following SDK component was not installed: source-25_**

Comment: yes it worked !! Thanks man you saved my day. upvoted you answer

Answer (score 1):

I clicked on cancel when " the following  SDK components was not installed" message appeared
Then I clicked finish
Then closed the android studio window.
Then went to start ,typed android studio,opened it again ,followed the same steps as I did when I was installing it for the first time.
This time everything went well, not a single error occured.
Hope this will help you too