# Android Studio installation Error ? "The following component was not installed: source-25"?

Tags: android, sdk, installation

[image: Error SnapShot]

Please help me fix this. I've tried to clear folders - registry a number of tines but this error is redundant & I really need help to fix it.

Android Studio installation Error ? I am getting "The following component was not installed: source-25" every time I'm trying to set up SDK part of installation?!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/40610343/6707985

Comment: Otherwise you might find something [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30004209/6707985)