# Android studio install error the following sdk component was not installed : tool

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to install android studio in one of my system, but not able to do so ..

Please find my error report in-line

```
Refresh Sources:
  Fetched Add-ons List successfully
  Refresh Sources

Installing Archives:
  Preparing to install archives
  Download finished with wrong checksum. Expected 9aec685e03aaa8ebf9991502b5fda7db208693f1, got 702c0ed97ec7c728f270a25c79ad4068fd359a61.
  Done. Nothing was installed.
The following SDK component was not installed: tools
```

After some google and questions over SO I found solution which states that I need to uninstall my Antivirus. I did that, but still the same problem.

May some one please suggest me over this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your probleme is similar to this : [Android Studio doesn't start, fails saying components not installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27376465/android-studio-doesnt-start-fails-saying-components-not-installed)

Try to run it with administrator privilege.
Regards

Comment: Thanks Remy for your quick reply .. IM trying some of option like same only. Will let you know :)

Comment: No Success ... I did as well.

Comment: Clearing the SDK Manager cache: [Tools > Options > Clear] Cache and the reloading [Package > Reload] helps.


Finally a guess may be that forcing to use http for downloading repos may solve some problems [Tools > Options > Force https sources to be downloaded using http].