# Android Studio stops in Ubuntu

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-studio, android-sdk-tools

I'm trying to create a new android studio project, after setting the minimum sdk and... android studio enters a window that its title says "Installing Requested Components". It also says "there is nothing to update or install". Then it STOPS there and it does not create the new project. A friend told me to set this variable in `idea.properties` file so maybe it can solve my problem :

```
disable.android.android.first.run=true
```

but it did not help, so how can I fix this problem?

I use ubuntu 15.10

Comment: How much memory do you have on your computer?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27376465/android-studio-doesnt-start-fails-saying-components-not-installed

Answer (score 0):

From my observation `Android Studio` doesn't work well with 15.10. I had the same issue and went back to 14.04.03. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :
 
go to your android studio directory and find **studio.sh** ussually it can find in bin folder, and type this in your terminal : `sudo ./studio.sh` 
hope it helps