# Installing Android Studio - SDK components not installed

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools

Getting this error always.

[image: Please check the screenshot for more details]

Please check the screenshot for more details

Comment: I am also facing same problem when installing fresh android studio

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked if there is an error in your connection? What was the error when installing Android Studio. Would be helpful if you can provide a screenshot where the details are shown like in this question -- [Android Studio doesn't start, fails saying components not installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27376465/android-studio-doesnt-start-fails-saying-components-not-installed) -- the more details you provide regarding the problem, the better.

Comment: Was supposed to add this as a comment..