# Android SDK Tools not installed

Tags: android, adb

I installed android studio to get adb. In setup wizard there was a message saying "The following SDK component was not installed: Android SDK Tools 25.1.7". And I think this is exactly what I need. What should I do?

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: Open the SDK Manager and install them?

Comment: You need to add the tools on system variables

Comment: Third time did it...

Comment: The Variables already are in system ? Try open a console in some place and run ADB devices

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To install Android SDK Tools 25.1.7

1. Start Android Studio
2. Open the SDK Manager: click Tools > Android > SDK Manager or click SDK Manager  in the toolbar.
3. In the SDK Tools tab, select Android SDK Tools 25.1.7 by clicking the check box so it shows a checkmark
4. To update the selected packages, click on OK

See more information [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update.html).

Answer (score 1):

Run the setup wizard again as the administrator (or use sudo) and it should work. If not, check your firewall and proxy.

For more information, check out this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27376465/android-studio-doesnt-start-fails-saying-components-not-installed).