# Android studio installation failed: SDK components were not installed

Tags: android, android-studio

Android Studio Component failed to install:

While installing Android studio SDK in Windows, 64 bit using the wizard; I encountered this error
“The following SDK components were not installed: sys-img-x86-addon-google_apis-google-21 ”

Can someone please help me where the possible error is?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27376465/android-studio-doesnt-start-fails-saying-components-not-installed

Comment: If you can open Android Studio, then you can go and update manually in SDK Manager.