# Android Studio preDexDebug After Adding jar File

Tags: java, android, jar

I have a framework of my own that I use for in-class tasks (school class, not Java class), and I made it into a `.jar` file so that whenever I make changes to the framework, I can just drag and drop it into Android Studio. Everything worked well for the past 5 or so class tasks, and now all of a sudden I'm getting a `preDexDebug failed` error when parsing my `.jar` after clicking run. I tested this on a blank project. The project has a total of 2 `.jar`s: Gson, and my own jar. It prints out `preDexDebug failed` right after I pull in my own `.jar`... I've wrestled with this for two infuriating hours, and I don't know what I can do to fix this at all...

I've tried rebuilding, cleaning, checking `gradle.build` for duplicates, replicating the project multiple times, and also compiling and copying the `.jar` multiple times as well.

Ubuntu x64 with 64 bit Oracle JDK 1.8.0_31. Using Java bundled with the JDK

Android Studio output:

```
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72103Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42103Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJava
:app:preDexDebug
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:","position":{},"original":"UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)","position":{},"original":"com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:472)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:472)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:704)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:704)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:673)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:673)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$300(Main.java:83)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$300(Main.java:83)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:602)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:602)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"...while parsing reactor/communications/ClientEndpointTCP.class","position":{},"original":"...while parsing reactor/communications/ClientEndpointTCP.class"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"1 error; aborting","position":{},"original":"1 error; aborting"}
```

Comment: Your error sure makes it look like you may have changed something in "reactor/communications/ClientEndpointTCP.class" to cause the problem.  This might be a good time to start using a version control system to track changes in your code, so that you could easily back up to a known good version and figure out what exact modification is responsible.

Comment: I just realized that this is the first time I've compiled everything on my desktop. It always worked on my laptop, which has OpenJDK 1.7, and there's another person that also had the `bad magic` error on here. I looked into it, and it seems that the Android SDK only officially supports Java 7, so the error makes sense now. I'm going to try compiling on my laptop for the moment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out Java 8 is not yet supported by the Android SDK (Or something along those lines). Installing Oracle JDK 7 on my desktop, and recompiling my `.jar` fixed the issue completely.

The most important part was in the second line of the error produced: "`bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)`". 0x34 is hex for 52, which means that the binaries are targeted for JREs that support Java 8, but Android Studio's system requirements state that JDK 7 is required

Steps to switch to Oracle JDK 7:

1. Download JDK `.tar` from Oracle's site
2. Untar contents to `/opt/`
3. `sudo update-alternatives --install /bin/java java /opt/jdk*version*/jre/bin/java 1023`
4. `sudo update-alternatives --install /bin/javac javac /opt/jdk*version*/bin/javac 1023`
5. `sudo update-alternatives --install /bin/jar jar /opt/jdk*version*/bin/jar 1023`

https://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-sun-oracles-proprietary-java-jdk-6-7-8-or-jre

Comment: Can you provide a link on how to switch to Java 7?