# AndroidPlot + Android studio compilation fails - 'Attribute "backgroundColor" has already been defined'

Tags: androidplot

I am just starting with androidplot and Android Studio. When I am adding the dependencies line in my `build.gradle`, Android Studio is not able to compile my app. It fails with following error:

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"error",
        "text":"Attribute \"backgroundColor\" has already been defined",
        "sources":[{"file":"/home/user/code/<app>/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values/values.xml",
        "position":{"startLine":282}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
```

Any idea what is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, this error does not appear to be related to Androidplot.  A quick google search on "AGPBI android" brought up several similar error results (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29255682/execution-failed-for-task-apppredexdebug) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28653135/android-studio-predexdebug-after-adding-jar-file) that all appear to have been caused by trying to use Java 1.8.  I'd start by double checking the your installed JDK version.