# How to resolve invalid source release error in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

I am using Intellij and I am trying to run a simple hello world android application. But i get the following error.

Error:java: invalid source release: 8

What could be the problem, any help?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android only supports java 7 so I assume that somewhere in your gradle/Intellij settings java 8 as source version is set. See this answer for more information: [Which JDK version (Language Level) is required for Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17869069/which-jdk-version-language-level-is-required-for-android-studio)