# Android device keeps disconnecting from adb / eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, adb

So I've read nearly every stack overflow answer about this issue, but still no solution.  My device keeps getting disconnected.  I've switched through 12 wires, I've tried every USB port; nothing.  Eclipse keeps dropping the connection.  It happens most often when I enter debug mode.  Has anyone found a solution to this? Is this a bug in the new update?  Seriously, this makes debugging and testing so painful.  It slows down my testing by at least 3 times.  There has to be a better solution.

Comment: I'm having the same issue with multiple Android devices on my Macbook Air

Comment: Possible duplicate of [macbook adb cannot open interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35650024/macbook-adb-cannot-open-interface)

Comment: You can use adb over tcp/wifi, some deleted answers here mention that and it worked very well for me! Quite easy-to-use and much more reliable. http://debuggingisfun.blogspot.com/2014/03/android-adb-over-wifi-and-random.html

Comment: It started happening very often with Android 8. Connecting through Wifi is much more stable

Answer (score 9):

First thing I tend to try is the following commands in cmd/terminal

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

And lastly,

```
adb devices
```

To check the device is connected.

Following that I'd try restarting the device, and perhaps as a last resort uninstall/reinstall it's drivers.

Edit: also, do you have access to another device? In the past I've had issues with specific devices constantly dropping out.

Comment: So basically my solution is to run adb kill-server and start-server and devices every time this happens.  But this happens every 5 minutes.  So not a very great solution.  Especially when I'm in the middle of debugging something.  On top of that, sometimes restarting it doesn't actually fix it.  Sometimes I have to restart adb up to 5 times before it works.

This happens on the following devices: Nexus 7 (2nd gen), HTC One, Nexus S.  Is something seriously wrong with Eclipse?

Comment: This is also happening on Galaxy Nexus now.  Has to be an issue with eclipse.

Comment: Is it possible that the ADT bundle for Mac is garbage and I need to install the official eclipse and install ADT on top of it. Will try that. Yay framework tools!

Comment: My device Nexus 7 with custom rom is also dropping and I need to reconnect cable. Maybe it can be custom rom problem ?

Comment: I had this problem with ADB and resetting it after every test does not always help. When it comes to stability, resetting ADB will not work on a long term period.

Comment: I found that restarting my Nexsus 5 sometimes solves the problem.

Answer (score 7):

I experience that when my nexus7 2012 kept disconnecting; root cause was the USB3 connection. 
Changing to a USB2 port fixed my issues; can you try switching to a lower speed port?

Answer (score 2):

I was having a very similar problem but using Android Studio on OS X. By default Android Studio points to an SDK inside it's application bundle so I changed the SDK location setting to point to another version of the Android SDK I had downloaded manually and this seems to have fixed the disconnection issues I was having.

Instructions for changing the SDK location setting can be found in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16582792/158522).

Answer (score 2):

My connected device (an Acer) was working a treat until I rebooted my mac.  After the reboot, Eclipse dropped the connection every single time I ran the app.  I tried two cables and every port in my iMac but nothing worked. I had to disconnect and reconnect the device for every run (a real pain when debugging!).

What worked for me was to run the app. When the window appeared to choose the device to run on (which was empty), I disconnected then reconnected the device, but before clicking to run, I checked the box (bottom left) to use this device for each run.  It now runs every time directly on the device.

Answer (score 2):

a unpowered usb hub did fix the problem for me. it was happening on both my samsung s6 and my sony z5 premium.and both on my pc and my mac. (using android studio).

Comment: Why did someone vote this down? It it a legitimate suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Use short usb cable. The shorter the length of cable, the more stable the adb connection. I had the same problem for long time. I changed the cable to shorter one and I haven't got that problem anymore.