# macbook adb cannot open interface

Tags: android, macos, usb, adb, nexus6

I am encountering a problem with Android ADB debugging through USB.

Using Macbook Air 2013 and trying to connect Nexus 6 dev phone.

On the MAC Android Studio, android latest sdk is installed.

When I do

```
adb kill-server
adb devices
```

I get:

```
adb I   661  9881 usb_osx.cpp:259] Found vid=18d1 pid=**** serial=*****
adb I   661  9881 usb_osx.cpp:259] 
adb E   661  9881 usb_osx.cpp:331] Could not open interface: e00002c5
adb E   661  9881 usb_osx.cpp:265] Could not find device interface
```

So it found the device, vendor id, product id and serial match what I find in the system information for the Nexus 6.

Following suggestions found online I tried - but no success - the following to resolve:

- dis- and reenabling debugging mode on the phone, also switching between USB configs for charging, MTP, PTP, RNDIS, Audio Source, MIDI, always making sure the authoriztation for the Mac's RSA fingerprint is given
- closing Android Studio / DDMS, killing adb through 'kill-server' command as well as killing process through Apple activity monitor
- run adb as root
- reboot the Mac several times
- reboot the Nexus 6
- reinstall Android SDK completely
- tried with another debugging enabled Android Device (Samsung Galaxy Tab, also here adb found correct device info but cannot access interface with same error)
- tried with 3 different USB cables, all cables which were originally shipped with Android devices

Through google I learned that error code e00002c5 means the device is already in use by another driver.

I had recently installed Sophos Home Antivir. Thinking that this might prevent ADB from opening the device interface, I uninstalled Sophos completely with the provided uninstaller and rebooted the Mac.

Any hint is appreciated:

- which steps to resolve?
- as e00002c5 seems to be a clear indicator that another driver has the device in use, how to find out which process that is and how to stop it from doing that

Comment: I am having the same problem with a 2015 Macbook Pro and a Nexus 6P.  Tried all of those steps with the same e00002c5 error.  If I boot in safe mode, adb works, which tends to the suggest another driver.  Still looking for a way to see what else would have that port open.

Comment: Have you ever installed "EasyTether"? if yes that may be the culprit. 
Then,  Open up the Finder.
- Click on your Mac's hard drive in the left pane.
- You should see a short list of folders. Open the one titled "System".
- Open "Library".
- Open "Extensions".
- Look for the file named "EasyTetherUSBEthernet.kext", and drag it to the trash. Your computer might ask for your authorization, so confirm the action.
- Restart your computer to clear all traces of EasyTether's driver from memory.

Comment: @IsankaWijerathne - I moved the EasyTetherUSBEthernet.kext to another folder and rebooted, and all kinds of software I installed started recognizing the android device.  This solves the problem for those of us who used EasyTether in our past... You should put that as an answer!

Answer (score 165):

I ran into this error as well, and it turned out that the problem for me was that a [Stetho](http://facebook.github.io/stetho/) tab was open in Chrome (i.e. a tab at URL chrome://inspect/#devices ), which I guess was causing the device to be in use. Closing that tab, then running `adb kill-server`, made `adb devices` work again.

Comment: same/similar solution - closed chrome://inspect/#devices on my mac and then ran the restart commands made it work. I also closed the file transfer manager program, but not sure if that helped.

Comment: Clearly a pattern emerges here, I had the same issue with a chrome://inspect tab opened, I almost lost all hope. Thanks for the find!

Comment: This should be accepted. That is the issue. In my case I didn't have to kill-server, just closing the tab in chrome.

Comment: Thanks you! Saved my day. I use to have the same issue with gap debug, never thought chrome inspect would also cause this problem.

Comment: I was getting random reboots and adb disconnects. It was driving me crazy. Closing chrome://inspect worked. Thank you Alan.

Comment: Holy crap this was driving me nuts and I stumbled upon this answer. I thought my phone and ALL of my usb cables were faulty. THANK YOU.

Comment: exactly my case here. this answer should be at the top.

Comment: This problem had irritated me very long time. I think I found real solution finally! Thank you!

Comment: I didn't had that tab opened, but then I opened it and unchecked the "Discover USB devices" and "Discover network targets" checkboxes. Worked.

Answer (score 8):

Same symptoms with a Galaxy S7 attached to Mac via USB. In my case, I had the Tizen IDE for Samsung Gear Development open. That also prevented adb working properly. Closing the Tizen IDE immediately helped.

In case you connect the mobile phone the first time, you may already have acknowledged the authorization for the computer on the phone. You have to delete the authorization on the phone and re-connect / re-auth it. Otherwise, the device will show in the device list, but is unauthorized. (I.e. you can't debug...)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using VirtualBox and have a virtual machine opened, you are probably trying to use adb from your host while it is plugged on your virtual machine. The problem is that you cannot have your device plugged on both at the same time.

**Solution** : Uncheck your device on the bottom right panel if it is detected by your Virtual Machine.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you have been accessing your device on virtual box and now trying to access it from your host OS, first you have to disconnect your device from the virtual box. To do that go to `setting> USB > unchecked the device from list`

> Then unplug your phone first and replug it. Or kill and start the server using `>adb kill-server` 
>   `>adb start-server`. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue with the message "Could not open interface: e00002c5". e00002c5 indicates that another app is using the device. Tizen studio was the app causing this issue.
Closed Tizen IDE and connected devices were available in the adb devices list.

Comment: I wanted to add that Docker also doesn't play nicely with ADB, apparently.

Answer (score 0):

I was debugging my Mobillyo app with a LG K4 phone. I closed Android Studio then enabled USB Debugging in the phone settings,left the settings open,  reopened Android Studio did RUN, a dialog opend with the phone info and Unauthorized, was asked to approve on the phone, touched Ok and it worked.