# ERROR: Failed to deploy to device, no devices found -cordova using visual studio

Tags: android, cordova, visual-studio-2013, phonegap-cli

I am developing an Apache Cordova mobile app using Visual Studio 2013. When I run my app in device mode I get the following error:

**ERROR: Failed to deploy to device, no devices found**

I have already **enabled USB debugging** in the developer options.
[image]

Comment: How have you connected the device to the machine? are you using a real device or an emulator?

Comment: i have connected android mobile(real device) via USB cable

Comment: have you checked if your android debug bridge(adb) service is running and have you added adb to PATH, and have you run the adb command to check connected devices?

Comment: I have two mobile one is working fine but other one shows this error. I have checked adb command its not showing any device(mobile which shows this error) and please tell me how to check adb sevice running or not

Comment: Try your question at: [Google Group of Cordova/Phonegap](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/phonegap)

Answer (score 69):

I have had problem that I have got "device not found" after first working connection an next reconnection. I have found solution by closing chrome://inspect/#devices tab in chrome dev tools. Hope this help someone. Happy coding!

Credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36662403/861615

Comment: This Answer helped me today. Thank you.

Comment: So simple. So helpful!

Comment: OMG, I can't believe that the solution is just as simple as this! Should be a bug of chrome or adb?...

Answer (score 35):

### Restart the adb server:

Try to restart your adb (Android debug bridge) server with following commands in your command line:

```
Path\to\adb\adb kill-server
Path\to\adb\adb start-server
```

On Windows, your `path\to\adb` might be something like `C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools` or `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools` depending on the installation of your Android SDK.

Afterwards, check if your device is found:

```
Path\to\adb\adb devices
```

Console output with a connected device might look like this on Windows command line:
[image: Console output of adb kill-sever, adb start-server and adb devices]

### Install OEM USB drivers:

If `adb devices` does not show any device, even after restarting your adb server, make sure you have your original equipment manufacturers (OEM) driver installed. [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html) offers further information on this and a [list of links](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/oem-usb#Drivers) for all the important manufacturers.

Comment: That did the trick for me. Just pointing out: I use Windows and the path to ADB is `C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools`

Comment: Good call, I added possible paths to the adb.exe.

Comment: Adding the OEM driver is what fixed it for me, thanks!  (Samsung Galaxy for example, http://developer.samsung.com/galaxy/others/android-usb-driver-for-windows)

Comment: Path on mac is `~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb`, I also had to reboot my android device itself.

Comment: Where is this on *Mac*?

Comment: For linux environments, there is no need to give adb commands with the path of adb execeutable. You can just type:
    adb kill-server
    adb start-server
    adb devices 

directly. Maybe an edit on the answer would be nice

Answer (score 10):

Try a different cable, mine works with one of my cables, but not the other.

Comment: This should definitely always be your first troubleshooting step.

Answer (score 8):

Test if your device appears when you write `adb devices` in your CLI

If not, just  change between the different options of conection, displayed in your phone. Usually works with PTP or MTP.

When the device appears, that should work. If you can't make it appear, just check your adb path or android drivers.

Comment: You may need to connect, disconnect and re-connect the USB cable a few times. I've had issues where devices are not always recognised on the first connection. Make sure the phone is unlocked (eg on the home screen) when you connect.

Answer (score 6):

For me, there was a prompt on my phone asking me to allow USB debugging, that I needed to allow. Before that my device was showing in the CLI but with the name "unauthorised". Kind of silly I know, but maybe this might help someome

Answer (score 0):

In addition to other answers above, you may need to install the device driver manually if you're developing with a Nexus device.

See [this page](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/oem-usb.html#InstallingDriver) on the Android developer site for installing *The Google USB Driver*.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the issue happened because the driver was not installed on the computer for my Nokia Android phone. `adb devices` command showed no devices. I followed the steps for Windows 7 listed on [Install USB driver](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/oem-usb#Drivers) and installed driver for **Android Composite ADB Interface**.

- In windows explorer, right click on computer, then click Manage
- Select device manager in the left pane and locate the unknown device in the right pane
- Expand the unknown device node and right click, select "Update Driver software.."
- Select "Browse my computer ..."
- Select "Let me pick from a list of device drivers ..."
- Select Android Composite ADB Interface

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but maybe helpfull.
I had to first connect the USB cable and then toggle on the USB debugging.

Comment: then, you were very lucky :)