# Android app not running on mobile device

Tags: android, emulation, usb-drive

I am just beginner for android. And I just create'Hello World' app for initiate in Android Studio. But I am not able to run this on my mobile device. When I connecting this to device, it's connected but showing an error message "No USB device or running emulators detected".

I did everything what I can but no luck.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38326366/android-studio-2-1-1-no-usb-devices-or-running-emulators-detected

Comment: Can you run `adb devices` from a command line?

Comment: I tried the method on @Pavan link and it works but now there is new error message "Application Installation Failed"

Comment: any error message or log with same

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it helps to switch the USB connection to one of the other modes available. (See your notification bar on the left when your phone is connected to your PC.)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to enable developer options on your phone -

> ### On Lollipop 5.1
>
> Go to About Phone
>
> Click 7 times on Build Number. Now Developer options are enabled
>
> Go back and Click Developer options
>
> Enable USB debugging under Debugging.

[Android Studio 2.1.1: "no usb devices or running emulators detected"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38326366/android-studio-2-1-1-no-usb-devices-or-running-emulators-detected)

Comment: Thanks Now I can show the device while run the application but now there is new error message "Application Installation Failed". What's this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to kill and restart adb server through terminal. Also there might be a case that usb driver are not installed.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to follow few steps:

1. Install PDA Net on your PC.
   http://pdanet.co/
2. Make sure your USB cable is in properly working condition.
3. Make sure USB debugging is "ON" on your Android Device.
4. Now when you will connect your phone with PC, it will automatically install some drivers. Let it install. When PC is done with driver installation, it will show a pop-up on your phone. You have to allow your PC your access your phone through that pop-up on your phone.

Try it, I hope it will work!