# ADB disconnecting after a few minutes

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, android-studio-2.2

After upgrading to Android Studio 2.2, adb will disconnect from my devices after a few minutes (~ 15 mins). I have to either re plug the device or disable ADB and renable every time. It happens with all devices. This is on MacOS Sierra. Is there a timeout setting they have added?

Comment: does that happens when the screen goes off?

Comment: maybe a bad usb cable

Comment: @Dionis L happens all usb cables

Comment: @David happens when screen is left on too

Comment: Why this question had -1? This is actually happening. Downloading the update.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is with ADB and it is reported in the bug tracker: [Issue 219085: adb does not work reliably on MacOS Sierra.](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=219085)

Answer from the thread:

> The fix has been released in the Beta Preview Channel, we apologize
>   for the inconvenience.or more information on how to use the Beta Preview Channel, please consult http://tools.android.com/download/studio

**Edit-1**:
Upgrading 2.2 to 2.2.1 or uninstalling the Android Studio-2.2 and installing the 2.2.1 won't work. Try to do clean uninstall by following the thread [How to completely uninstall Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18458893/549978) and check.

Comment: I think this it, I think I actually upgraded Android studio after Sierrra, or the problem started happening after upgrading to Sierra.

Comment: I faced the issue in Android Studio-2.2 after upgrading to sierra, before that it worked fine on Yosemite.

Comment: @blizzard after updating the android studio still facing the issue !

Comment: @blizzard I had no problems after completly uninstalling Android Studio and reinstalling 2.2.2. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

> I ran into this error as well, and it turned out that the problem for
>   me was that a Stetho tab was open in Chrome (i.e. a tab at URL
>   chrome://inspect/#devices ), which I guess was causing the device to
>   be in use. Closing that tab, then running adb kill-server, made adb
>   devices work again.

original answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/36662403/3290623

Comment: You saved my life my friend! It was this problem!

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the drivers again and restart the Mac, it works for me on AS 2.2

Answer (score 0):

if you do not want to upgrade your Android studio to preview version , just open the sdk manager and upgrade the sdk build-tools, then restart android studio .  it works for me !

[image]