# Android studio on Mac cannot detect connected USB phone

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, usb

Constant issue with being able to connect an Android device via USB to Android Studio running on a Mac.

Tried numerous things like:

- Switching USB debugging mode on Android to MTP or PTP
- Restarting the Android devices and Android Studio and/or Mac
- trying `adb kill-server`and then `adb devices`, which usually resulted in:

  > List of devices attached
  >
  > daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037
  >
  > adb E   655 23135 usb_osx.cpp:327] Could not open interface: e00002c5
  >
  > adb E   655 23135 usb_osx.cpp:289] Could not find device interface
  >
  > daemon started successfully

  But not actually finding the connected device.

Comment: check if tools->android->enable adb integration is checked. If not check it

Comment: @AbhisekLamsal Thanks, but I found the answer (posted below). It was working fine until I started using Tizen Studio/Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some great responses that worked for others, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7136003/2332942) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36662403/2332942) which seemed to work for others.

In my case, the issue was Tizen Studio (I was working on a watch app for Samsung Gear). Through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35650024/2332942) poster's research, found that the adb error `could not open interface: e00002c5` implies that the usb device is already in use by some other driver.

So it seems Tizen Studio takes up the usb driver resource even though it is not using it. Quitting the application will automatically allow `adb devices` to list your device and run the project on it.

Hope this helps other lost souls.

Comment: how to stop tizen studio, i dont see tizen was running

Comment: For me, it was chrome inspect I used for network intercepting using stetho interceptor. I closed that window and studio automatically detected the device.

Comment: thanks for the references. for me it seems to have been the cable. Strange, the cable that wasn't working is pretty new and *was* working, but that's the way it goes with cables.

Answer (score 12):

I just wanted to write it down in case someone else comes across this issue.
It took me more than a couple of days to solve this while I was banging my head trying to understand what seems to be the problem.
**Note: For me it was a cable issue.**

I have Nexus6P with 2 original cables:

1. Type-C to Type-C
2. Short Type-C to regular USB

The problem was I was trying to hook the cable 1 directly from the Nexus to the Mac Pro (which didn't work since I think the Mac has a thunderbolt protocol on the Type-C inputs)

Then I tried a Type-C to regular USB cable with an adapter from to make it Type-C to Type-C (bear in mind this wasn't the original cable I got with my phone)

Only when I used the original short cable (cable 2) with an adapter it worked.
Although the non-original cable I used was a high-end cable - it still didn't work

Hope it helps other people who struggle with this

Comment: Interesting observation. Sometimes the cables are meant for charging only and not for data transfer.

Comment: Funny thing is that the cable stated it's for data and charging :(

Comment: @Loves2Develop same issue for me, same state but android studio do not see the device because of cable.

Answer (score 0):

My limited mobile developer-experience is on xcode so attaching an android-phone to android studio was not straigtforward. Found this thread where I tried the suggestions to no avail. Then a new search-result pointed to Android's [getting started guide](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-compose-connect-device#2), macos in my case. From the guide.

```
On your Android device, tap Settings > About phone.
Tap Build number seven times.
Return to Settings and then tap System > Developer options.
If you don't see Developer options, tap Advanced options
Tap Developer options and then tap the USB debugging toggle to turn it on.
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help everyone but figured I would share my "odd" solution.

So I literally just switched over the connection of my cable from the right side of the Mac over to the left hand side and then it worked! Android Studio recognized my device.

Details of my situation:

- 2019 Macbook on Ventura 13.4.1
- Android Device running 8.1
- Regular USB to USB C cable, along with an adapter for the regular USB

The regular USB with the adapter was plugged into my laptop on left hand side, top port (if it makes any difference here). The USB C part of my cable was plugged into my device.

Hopefully this helps out people!

Answer (score -2):

if Xcode runs please turn it off
then everything worked again