# Android Studio debugging keeps displaying "Allow USB debugging?" PopUp

Tags: adb

I am using Android Studio version

```
Android Studio 3.4.1
Build #AI-183.6156.11.34.5522156, built on May 1, 2019
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b01 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
macOS 10.14.5
```

with multiple Android devices including Pixel XL with Android Q (QPP4.190502.019)

All my test devices have started repeatedly displaying the

```
"Allow USB debugging?" PopUp
```

And losing ADB connectivity

What recent update has caused this behavior?

**UPDATE**

I reboot my laptop daily, as do my colleagues.

I and my colleagues have not updated USB drivers.

Ive tried multiple USB leads, as have my colleagues.

I've tried multiple Android devices and versions from 21 to Q
Devices include Pixel, Pixel 2, Pixel 3 & Pixel C, and Samsung S9, as have my colleagues.

I have revoked USB privileges and re granted on all devices, as have my colleagues.

The issue still persists

Comment: Have a look what I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41468370/android-studio-on-mac-cannot-detect-connected-usb-phone), if you haven't tried them yet

Comment: Google Chrome inspect page may cause this problem.

Answer (score 1):

try to check the changelog for android studio update or have you try to enable the usb debugging in your device.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't you installed/reinstalled Android USB drivers recently, if so try to reboot your system

It can also be caused by your broken USB cable, try to replace it with another one and check

Answer (score 0):

I think you haven't checked never ask again option, that is why it's asking continuously.
So you can try to check that box if you haven't done that.

Answer (score 0):

For others who might run into this problem, this started happening to me after I updated the OS version of my device. Restarting the device solved the issue.