# Support ActionBar and GameBaseActivity

Tags: android, android-actionbar, google-play-services

I want to use the support action bar so I need to extend my activity from ActionBarActivity in the support library. However my activity is ready extending from BaseGameActivity...

I tried to modify the BaseGameActivity to extend from ActionBarActivity instead of FragmentActivity, but lots of errors were reported in the SDK XML about themes after I add the support library to gamebaseutils librarys, the errors were like:

```
...BaseGameUtils] C:\Program Files\adt-bundle-windows\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\themes_base.xml:83: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar'.
```

Do you have any idea of getting them work together? Thank you!

Comment: I did the same and it worked for me. Maybe the problem is in the supportlibraries?

Comment: @Ragnar, Did you use the ActionBarActivity from support library? If I use the ActionBarActivity from the SDK, it won't have such problems.

Comment: You should include the support library in the basegameactivity in the project config (gradle files)

Comment: @Ragnar, Thank you for the reply! I think I did that. (quote: "after I added the support library to gamebaseutils"). I in the end gave up this approach and instead let the app only support Android 4.0+. Thank you all the same for the comments!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18370816/no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-style-theme-holo-light-darkacti