# Android appcompatv7 : error in resources

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

Today when i opened my eclipse today and when i created a new android project. appcompatv7 gets automatically gets imported as per the new sdk. But the appcompatv7 is showing some error. When i am expanding the appcompatv7 there is error in res --> values-large --> theme_base.xml and res --> values-large-v14 --> theme_base.xml. the error in those xml file shows "no resources found that  matches the following name". please help and due to this my new project is also showing error.

```
<resources>

    <style name="Theme.Base.AppCompat.DialogWhenLarge"
       parent="Theme.Base.AppCompat.Dialog.FixedSize" />

    <style name="Theme.Base.AppCompat.Light.DialogWhenLarge"
       parent="Theme.Base.AppCompat.Dialog.Light.FixedSize" />

</resources>
```

Comment: sdk version in manifest of appcompatv7 is showing 7

Comment: just right click project and choose Androdi Tools and select the clear lint warning and run your app.

Comment: done. But nothing happens. there is error in both appcompatv7 project and also Test application that i created

Comment: @ShreksDeveloper: clean your project and restart ide

Comment: cleaned the project. Restarted also. But it is not working.

Comment: try this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18370816/no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-style-theme-holo-light-darkacti

Answer (score 3):

For what it worth, I had a similar compile problem, and found out that Google's AppCompat library had a breaking API change with a few of the base themes.
I fixed that by renaming:

`Theme.AppCompat.Light` **to** `Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light`
and `Theme.Base.AppCompat.Dialog.FixedSize` **to** `Base.Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.FixedSize`

(note the **Base** prefix).