# error changing api level android version from 8 to 12

Tags: java, android, eclipse, manifest

I'm having problem changing minSdkVersion of an android application in eclipse, i want to change from 8 to 12 and every time it doesn't work, that are the first errors:

`[2014-11-27 22:15:07 - BlaBlaPark1.3] C:\Users\Filippo\Desktop\EclipseAndroid2.0\programmi\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:75: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'.
[2014-11-27 22:15:07 - BlaBlaPark1.3] 
[2014-11-27 22:15:07 - BlaBlaPark1.3] C:\Users\Filippo\Desktop\EclipseAndroid2.0\programmi\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:79: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.CloseMode'.
[2014-11-27 22:15:07 - BlaBlaPark1.3] 
[2014-11-27 22:15:07 - BlaBlaPark1.3] C:\Users\Filippo\Desktop\EclipseAndroid2.0\programmi\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:83: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.Overflow'.
[2014-11-27 22:15:07 - BlaBlaPark1.3]`

maybe i need to add appcompat_v_7, i tryed but every time it give me a lot of error

Answer (score 1):

if you have problems with appcompact 7 - there is a workaround

1. **right click you project** and from the menu go to **properties**
2. in the new window (shown in the picture) select **android**.
3. at the **lib section** (red rectangle) **remove appcompact7**
4. press **add** button and select appcompact7 again

[image]

if you want to manually change  your styles, go to your project, track down the problematic xml files, and replace

```
android:Widget.Material.ActionButton  --> Materials new layout
```

with this:

```
android:style/Theme.Holo.Light  --> Holo theme (from android HoneyComb and later)
```

Comment: now i'm not using appCompactv7, I'm using only google-play-service_lib have i to do the same you told me to do with appcompactv7 with that?

Comment: try to edit the style for each xml manually with the holo light string. take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18370816/no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-style-theme-holo-light-darkacti

Comment: where can i find the change that i have to do?

Comment: I'm using eclipse, the project compile correctly, but when i run with 8 version it work ok, when i use version 12 it doesn't work, it give me the first page (with small look change) but when i click for login it doesn't work (i want to pass to version 12 only to the map function) I already tryed to empty the emuletor, but nothing change

Comment: if yous wish to detect your moblie version ans execute a specific code for specific version you should try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093365/how-can-i-check-the-system-version-of-android