# error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.DeviceDefault.Light'

Tags: android

I was setting the style.xml to set it as another theme style

but after setting it it give out the error

```
error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the 
given name 'android:Theme.DeviceDefault.Light'.
```

here is my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.DeviceDefault.Light">   
</style>
</resources>
```

i try the answer too but it given out

[2016-03-08 18:15:53 - com.FF_studio.device_flash_1] F:\rico\android\work\com.FF_studio.device_flash_1\res\values-v14\styles.xml:3: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.DeviceDefault.Light'.
[2016-03-08 18:15:53 - com.FF_studio.device_flash_1] 
[2016-03-08 18:34:15 - com.FF_studio.device_flash_1] F:\rico\android\work\com.FF_studio.device_flash_1\res\values-v14\styles.xml:3: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light'.
[2016-03-08 18:34:15 - com.FF_studio.device_flash_1]

Comment: try with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18370816/no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-style-theme-holo-light-darkacti

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9832114/how-to-use-device-default-theme-for-app

Comment: Change your `parent` to another one, for example, `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`

Comment: parent="android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with this

```
parent="android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light"
```