# Importing an eclipse project in Android studio. Error with Gradle

Tags: android, eclipse, gradle, android-studio

**What I have:**

1. Eclipse Juno Service Release 2 working on windows 7 x64.
2. Android Studio updated to 0.2.8
3. ADT updated

**What I have done**

I have been developing with Eclipse for a long time and now I wanted to give a chance to Android Studio so I checked on google developers webpage and I downloaded and updated Android Studio to 0.2.8. As google says, I do need to export from eclipse creating the gradle file so I did it. After that, I opened Android studio and check what it says on google page: "Use gradle wrapper". Every time I try to import my project I get an error saying:

> Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions-snapshots/gradle-1.8-20130830160653+0000-bin.zip'.
>   Build file 'C:\Users\me\Eclipse\proyectos\myProject\build.gradle' line: 9
>   A problem occurred evaluating root project 'myProject'.
>   A problem occurred evaluating root project 'myProject'.
>   Gradle version 1.6 is required. Current version is 1.8-20130830160653+0000

What should I do? Everything I have looked on the net is for an update of the ide to 0.2.7 with a project that is imported and not to being imported.

**EDIT**

gradle file: (my project has a deppendency for which also I made a gradle file from Eclipse. "library" is actionbarSherlock library

> ```
> buildscript {
> repositories {
>     mavenCentral()
> }
> dependencies {
>     classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4'
> } } apply plugin: 'android'
> ```
>
> dependencies {
>       compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
>       compile project(':C::Users:me:Eclipse:proyectos:library') }
>
> android {
>       compileSdkVersion 16
>       buildToolsVersion "18.0.1"
>
> ```
> sourceSets {
>     main {
>         manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
>         java.srcDirs = ['src']
>         resources.srcDirs = ['src']
>         aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
>         renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
>         res.srcDirs = ['res']
>         assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
>     }
>
>     instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
> } }
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED**

Finally, after the new upgrades the error has been solved. If you have this error try to update ADT to r22.2.1 and Android Studio to 0.2.9. Then, export again gradle from eclipse and try it to import it from AS.

Maybe you will have now an error with sdk dir importing the file. If so, add the variable ANDROID_HOME to windows variables with the route of your android sdk and after rebotting the computer try it again. Remember that with AS there's a new installation of ADT so you have to update also that one or change the path as shown here https://stackoverflow.com/a/18409923/1200914

Answer (score 0):

You have used `Gradle 1.8`, as your error mentions, you should use `Gradle 1.6`. Download it from here http://services.gradle.org/distributions-snapshots

Comment: I thought that but I don't know where to change the option in Eclipse or Android Studio.

Comment: can you post your build.gradle file? it should locate at C:\Users\me\Eclipse\proyectos\myProject\build.gradle

Comment: ok now at your project settings select gradle and choose "Use gradle wrapper" instead of the bundled option. Then open your gradle-wrapper.properties and change distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.8-bin.zip

Comment: But is this on Android Studio? I can't do this because the project is not imported due to the error.

Comment: you can access project settings from preferences?

Comment: In Android studio, Gradle is an option of your project that you can access if you open it. Since the project is not imported I cannot open it with Android Studio and I cannot change that. If you refer to Eclipse, I haven't seen the option there.

Comment: ok, at control panel, installed programs list, can you see gradle listed there?

Comment: No it's not but anyway, it doesn't matter. I will forget about AS until they archieve version 0.5 or so. Thanks for your time.