# Problems with ActionBarSherlock in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, actionbarsherlock

i want to use `actionbarsherlock` and add this library to my app but when complie app gives the following error:

[image]

how to can solve this error?

Comment: upgrade to appcompat, which is google supported.

Comment: update adt, try to run gradle again. This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18801664/importing-an-eclipse-project-in-android-studio-error-with-gradle

Comment: How to upgrade appcompat?

Comment: Who knows how should I resolve my issue :(

Comment: Can you post your build.gradle ?

Comment: biuld.gradle is:

 buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4'

    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')

}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 7
    }
}

Answer (score 1):

You are running Android Studio 0.1, which is well over a year old. Please, please, please upgrade to a later version. Many bugs which prevent Android Studio from properly parsing compiler error messages have been fixed since then, and you should get better error output.