# Cannot set sdk location in imported project

Tags: android

Recently I imported this project from github (https://github.com/adlebzelaznog/colometer) into android studio 1.5.1 after downloading and extracting the zip and have had nothing but problems. In the project structure menu, the location of my sdk is present however when trying to build the project, I am getting an error saying that the location of my sdk is unknown:

Error:(1, 1) A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.

I really don't know whats wrong as I am just trying to use this guy's source code and don't know why importing it is so difficult. I also have tried setting the android_home variable in command prompt (I'm running windows 7).

Answer (score 0):

Try to check if SDK is correctly installed, refer to this [SDK Location not found Android Studio + Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19272127/sdk-location-not-found-android-studio-gradle) answer.If this does not work then I would suggest reinstall the SDK properly.

Comment: I have very simple solution of this, you have to just copy your local.properties file in the folder where project is stored and it will work like charm.Remeber in the root folder where project is stored.