# Android Studio SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable

Tags: android

I understand that there has been a lot of similar questions ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19272127/sdk-location-not-found-android-studio-gradle)) and answers provided in StackOverflow. But this does not solve the problem in the root cause.

Surely, it will work if I manually create a local.properties and add the sdk.dir into the file then place the file at the root folder of a new Android Project that I have cloned from github.

For the record, I have set my environment properly. I have added the following code in `.bash_profile`:

```
#android sdk
ANDROID_HOME=/Users/tonythompson/Library/Android/sdk;
export ANDROID_HOME
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

I have configured the path in Android Studio properly. But the problem is that every time when I import a new project, I have to copy the `local.properties` into the root folder of the project before it could be built successfully. Life could be so much better if we could skip this trivial steps.

Anyone has experienced similar issues?