# Android: SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable

Tags: android, gradle

I'm trying to run this sample project using GraphQL with the Apollo Android client: https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-android/tree/master/apollo-sample

I'm new to Android studio, here's what I did so far:

1. Installed Android Studio on my machine (mac)
2. Clone full [Apollo Android](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-android) repo
3. Started Android studio and opened the `apollo-sample` directory from the cloned repo as an Android project

I am now getting this build error:

> Error:SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.

**It's the same issue that's described in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19272127/sdk-location-not-found-android-studio-gradle) question, however none of the solutions of the suggested answer worked for me:**

I do have a `local.properties` file in the root directory of the project that has the `sdk.dir` set:

```
sdk.dir=/Users/nburk/Library/Android/sdk
```

I don't actually know where this entry is coming from, but it's definitely there. I'm assuming it points to the right location, the contents of that path are the following directories:

```
build-tools
emulator
extras
patcher
platform-tools
platforms
sources
tools
```

I also tried to set the `ANDROID_HOME` env var as suggested in the accepted answer but this didn't work either:

[image]

Comment: Setting the variable within the terminal of the IDE doesn't perform an `export` to the environment already determined when you start Android Studio. Try completely closing the process, then adding the variable to `~/.bashrc`, and see if that helps

Comment: ah thanks for the hint! now added `ANDROID_HOME` to `.bashrc` and completely closed Android Studio, restarted with new project and still get the same issue

Comment: Hmm. Personally, I use IntelliJ instead of Android Studio, and I have used Homebrew to install the SDK. Not sure if those make a huge difference, but the fact that your SDK Manager detects things that are installed, I think you configured it fine

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Native android build failed. SDK location not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32634352/react-native-android-build-failed-sdk-location-not-found)

Comment: Getting same issue, added `ANDROID_HOME` and restarted Android Studio worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening **SDK manager** in **Android studio** and see if the SDKlocation is set correctly.

Comment: yeah. it seems correct. is the android studio placed in Applications?

Comment: yes it is there. should the SDK path point to some location inside the application directory? I dont know why it points to `/Users/nburk/Library/Android/sdk`

Comment: the location is correct for sdk. its the default location of the sdk. Can you check with creating a new project in android studio and try to build that.

Comment: Did you manage to sort this out? If so please share your answer am having same issue but not getting any solution

Comment: Setting the path in Anrdoid Studio and in ANDROID_HOME and PATH variables was not enough for me. I had to create a `local.properties` file. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/32640154/1910855

Answer (score 0):

Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file

Go to System Properties -> Environment Variables -> Add Variable -> Put Variable Name and Value.

Add variable name: ANDROID_HOME and value: as your SDK path.