# Can't open Android samples using Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I just started using Android Studios and wanted to look at some of the sample code that Google already provides in their apk samples.

However, when I try importing a project, it tells me:
"You are using an old, unsupported version of Gradle. Please use version 1.8 or greater.
Please point to a supported Gradle version in the project's Gradle settings or in the project's Gradle wrapper (if applicable.)
Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)"

In my .gradle/wrapper/dists, I have gradle-1.6-bin and gradle-1.8-bin.
I tried updating the gradle to 1.8 from 1.6 in the gradle-wrapper.properties file in the project itself, but I can't seem to save the file after editing it.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Change line in build.gradle:

dependencies {
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
}
Step 2:

In the YourProject.iml file, delete the entire component name="FacetManager" tag.

Step 3

(Maybe not necessary): In the Android SDK manager, install (if not already installed) Android Support Repository under Extras.

Refer to these 2 links. It answers your question.

[getting error when importing project in android studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19633710/getting-error-when-importing-project-in-android-studio)

[Unable to import Eclipse project to Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19485981/unable-to-import-eclipse-project-to-android-studio)

Comment: How do you change the line? When I try saving it, it doesn't let me save as the gradle file because it's a read-only file.

Comment: Kindly refer to the second link i have posted and look the answer posted. It might help.

Comment: That's the exact link I was looking at and trying to do what they said but again, the files for me are read-only so I don't know how to overwrite that.

Comment: Can you please edit my answer with more details on how you figured out. It helps many others. Just a request.

Comment: Please don't edit your .iml files directly. What's the purpose of removing the FacetManager tag?