# Importing project into Android studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I am trying to import an Android library I've created into Android Studio. I've exported the app from Eclipse by going to File > Export > Gradle Build Files which completed successfully.

However, when I try and import the project into Android Studio I get the following error:

> You are using an old, unsupported version of Gradle. Please use
>   version 1.8 or greater. Please point to a supported Gradle version in
>   the projects Gradle settings or in the project's Gradle wrapper (if
>   applicable)

I've followed the instructions from [Unable to import Eclipse project to Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19485981/unable-to-import-eclipse-project-to-android-studio) but this hasn't worked.

Thanks for any help you can provide

Answer (score 5):

- Download Gradle 1.8: http://www.gradle.org/downloads
- Install/Copy it in a folder on your computer.
- Check what gradle installation you use in Settings (Strg+Alt+S) -> Gradle

[image]

- Check "use local gradle distribution" and point in "gradle home:" to the gradle installation

Comment: Thank You very much. It will helpful for my project.