# Android Studio Gradle error after update from 0.2.x to 0.3.1

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-studio, updates

I have recently updated my Android Studio from 0.2.9 to 0.3.1 and when I try to compile my project i get the error:

> org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException: Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.7-bin.zip'.: Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.7-bin.zip'.

I have tried to use the terminal and successfully cleaned and rebuilt by using **gradlew clean** and then **gradlew build**. I have even invalidated the caches by using `File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart` but I still can't build using Android Studio.

Do you have any ideas on why I have this problem and how can I fix it?

Edit #1 : When I go into `Settings -> Gradle` I get an error: "`Gradle location is unknown`". Is that the problem? Where should that path point to?

Comment: check this if it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19485981/unable-to-import-eclipse-project-to-android-studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed the issue by using the advice from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19485981/unable-to-import-eclipse-project-to-android-studio).

I have updated **gradle-wrapper.properties** from **<AppNameProject>/gradle/wrapper/**:

```
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.7-bin.zip
```

to

```
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.8-bin.zip
```

and **build.gradle** from **<AppNameProject>/<AppName>/**:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
}
```

to

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
}
```