# Android Eclipse to Android Studio ---> Project Structure

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I converted my Eclipse project to Android studio by following the instructions [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html). In the documentation it says the structure should be updated but from what I am seeing it hasn't.

Expected structure should be:

```
-src
    -main
        -java
        -res
```

but it pretty much maintained it's old structure as:

```
-res
-src
    -my.package.com
```

I noticed this when I was trying to add a jniLibs folder to 'main', but couldn't find it.

Has anyone had this problem before? Is there a way to update the project structure? Thanks!!

Comment: Thanks, but I've done that. It's the same thing the documentation says  to do.

Comment: The answer was in the post, but not the answer you provided. Here it is http://stackoverflow.com/a/22797387/2170265. Of course Google's documentation is outdated :(

Answer (score 1):

Check your build.gradle file.

You may have a configuration like this, where you override the project structure.

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir 'src/java'
        }
        resources {
            srcDir 'src/resources'
        }
    }
}
```