# Importing and converting Eclipse-made Android project from Github to Android Studio Gradle-build

Tags: android, github, import, gradle, android-studio

I'm trying to migrate from using Eclipse for my Android-project to the new Android Studio, and I'm having an issue related to Gradle.

What I want is for me to push the latest Eclipse-build to Github, and then be able to pull it down in Android Studio, having the latter automatically convert the project to a Gradle-build. If I'm reading the documentation right, the Android Studio import is supposedly able to do this.

When importing, I can choose between "Create project from exisiting sources" or "Import project from external model"

If I choose the first option, the project won't use Gradle (as far as I can see). If I choose the second, it seems to be looking for an already existing gradle buildfile "build.gradle" in my project.

So - Should I download a Gradle-plugin to Eclipse and make a gradle build-file there, or am I doing something wrong in the import?

It seems the only other questions I can find on SO is about importing and Eclipse export or simply how to pull a project from Github in Android Studio.

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

Importing and converting an existing Eclipse project into a Android Studio Gradle project is quite simple : 
File -> Import Project (in Android Studio)
Select the manifest of your Eclipse Android project.

Done.

There may be some dependacy management to deal with.

You can also take a look here : 
[How do you import an Eclipse project into Android Studio now?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22791150/how-do-you-import-an-eclipse-project-into-android-studio-now)

Comment: Yes, but that is not going through Github, as I want it to :-) I don't want to have to export from eclipse, import from AS, only then to create a new git repo for the converted project. 

Thank you for your answer, though :-)

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

- clone repo to location 1
- export from eclipse
- import to android studio in location 2
- copy the .hg files or whatever's applicable from 1 to 2
- commit from location 2 including deleting eclipse files

Now the repo will have the android studio project and not eclipse.