# Files missing after importing eclipse project into android studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I am importing eclipse project into android studio. But after importing my project does not properly compile in android studio because it does not contain AndroidManifest.xml and other files which help to compile the project. 
So, anyone suggest me to run my eclipse project into android studio.

Comment: How did you import the project?

Comment: which files are missing?

Comment: Try using this https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/migrate.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Migrating Eclipse to Android Studio with missing build.gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27929277/migrating-eclipse-to-android-studio-with-missing-build-gradle)