# How do I import from eclipse to android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I 'm new to Android Studio ... I was using eclipse and my project was associated with appcompat v7 and I watched that video of how to import your project folder to android studio from eclipse but I wondered what about the appcompat v7 do I forget about or what ?

Comment: The app compat dependency should be specified in your `build.gradle` file.

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22791150/how-do-you-import-an-eclipse-project-into-android-studio-now

Answer (score 0):

To get round this, look for refs in the project.properties or .classpath files that came in from the Eclipse project and remove/comment them out, eg

```
<classpathentry combineaccessrules="false" kind="src" path="/android-support-v7-appcompat"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use file>Import project. After it's imported go to build.gradle and paste:

```js
dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
}
```